# Grace Period to recover deleted answer content (User Removed)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, deleted-answers, deleted-users

Is there a way to place answers about to be deleted from **User Removed** events into some sort of Limbo for a short period, say 7 days.

On several occasions I have seen a question I know I have answered before.  But the question is gone - not even Google can find it using phrases I know were in the title, question and/or answer.  More than likely they evaporated as a result of a past "User Removed" adjustment.

This is **not** about lost rep, but **lost content**.  So why not some sort of Grace Period:

- User is removed for whatever reason
- All their questions/answers are removed from view but not physically deleted
- Answers you provided could  posted to the **Recently Deleted Answers** portion of your Answer List
- They remain in that state for 7 days before they are physically removed

If you get the "User Removed" notice, you could open the List and see what is going to be removed and decide if you want to salvage the content for use when (not if) the question comes up again.  Or perhaps you simply make a mental note that the answer is no longer available.

If the answer was not upvoted, you would not get the notice, so some content would still just disappear. A new "**Pending Deletion**" notice would be ideal, but I am trying to make as much use of existing features as possible.

(I got such a notice today after spending 15 minutes Googling for a good answer I had previously given.  I doubt it is the same answer, but irritated me and got me thinking.  After that, I tried to use the Data Explorer to find deleted answers but it seems they are either physically deleted for removed users or just not visible there).

Comment: +1 Its very annoying when you *know* something is a duplicate and you can't find it because its been deleted.

Comment: Why add grace period? Answers (maybe also questions), unless there are serious legal reasons, could be stored in the database indefinetely? 

Grace period works only if user is checking SO every day, which might be true for many, but I guess it is often not the case? Everybody needs a vacatioN!

Comment: Personally, I dont quite understand why upvoted Answers get deleted if a user simply quits (sock puppets, yes).  If someone thought it was good at some point, isnt it *still* good even if the OP quits?  Seems to go against the whole repository-of-all-programming-questions goal, but thats secondary.  Seven days was just an example, 14 might be better for more people.  A notice that they are going to evaporate and a chance to salvage decent answers is the goal.

Comment: SO refusing to show me content I contributed just makes me regret contributing here instead of writing for my blog.

Comment: Questions should *only* be deleted if the question has a score of -1 or lower on user deletion.

Comment: @hichris123, but what if the question has a good *answer*?

Comment: @hichris123 also, I have seen plenty of questions with a -1 score that were really perfectly fine and just got dinged by some random person for whatever unknown reason. I think it should be at least -2 before the question is auto-deleted.

Comment: @eddie_cat: You could have saved any of those questions by applying a single upvote to them, but you apparently chose not to.

Comment: We're talking about a fairly tiny # of posts here, most of them not very good. Yes, we could put work into making sure nothing of value is lost here - but we could probably do the same for affected answers by [fixing crappy posts when answering them](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/)... And benefit a whole lot more answers as well.

Comment: Man, the first eight Shogs were more optimistic.

Comment: Uber-Meta duplicate of [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860), which has since been marked as 'status-completed'. I'm marking this as completed too, because questions with a negative score but with positively scoring answers are no longer auto-deleted.

Answer (score -21):

I don't see what the fuss is all about.

If a question or answer gets deleted by the community or by the Roomba, it means that the post was not of sufficient value to be kept around.  If it's not valuable now, it's not going to be valuable during a grace period either.

If a user account gets deleted by simple disassociation, all of their posts are preserved, so there's no need for a grace period in that case.

If the user gets removed and the posts are removed with them, it means that the vast majority (usually all) of their contributions are either spam, or violate the Terms of Service in some way.  Again, no need for a grace period.

Comment: I think the big concern is that while the question is likely junk, upvoted answers probably aren't. But the good answers are still thrown out, with the users contributing them having no way of salvaging their contributions.

Comment: @Kevin: Questions with upvoted answers are protected from automatic deletion.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006.  It still takes three votes for the community to delete a question.  **Pro Tip:** Don't answer crappy questions.

Comment: "The Fuss" is that it is very annoying to *know* you answered some question but cant find it because it has been deleted for one reason or another.  "The Fuss" is about being notified with some specifics as to *what* is going away.  Since it is possible for an answer to of more value than the question, some short period of time to copy out an answer which is complex or long would be nice, thats all.  I am not up on all the deletion machinations, but users who simply quit seem to take upvoted answers with them or we would not see negative User Removed adjustments (*not* worried about the rep!)

Comment: @Plutonix Regardless of whether I agree or not, it seems Robert Harvey's position is that it is your fault for answering crappy questions (presumable on the grounds that it acts as an enabler for other crappy questions).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Note that the roomba is not relevant in this case; this is solely about user -> question -> answer deletion cascading, which [does happen regardless of answer score](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote). (Or question score, for that matter.)

Comment: I don't know why this is at -20. I'm pretty sure I flagged an answer blasted by a deleted user to be recovered at some point. As a 20k rep user I could see it anyway given a link to it, and the question wasn't deleted.