# My top answer was deleted and my worst question is not deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers, specific-answer

It's like the question always haunted me after the incident.

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times/26716300?noredirect=1), where I made my best answer ever, in terms of quality and number of upvotes *(it had 45 or something and my current best is 5)*. I was really proud that my answer was good and I was dreaming that maybe one day I might be as good as the users here who have huge reputations and usually give very good answers.

The answer was even viewed by people of my university where I am a student and one of the professors did put the question *(a bit modified)* in the midterm. I was really glad, but all of a sudden it was gone! A high-reputation user had requested me to post the very same answer to another question, so the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26834369/2411320) is still "alive", but in a question that differs a bit from the one that I had answered.

On the other side, I recently made my worst [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750973/remove-adjacent-words) *(I even voted for it to close)*. It's really a horrible question, it's a pity I can't downvote it. I don't care about the -2, I care about the fact that this question can't provide anything to future users, because it is too unclear. So I flag it for moderators to see it and gave a close vote, but nothing. I couldn't delete the question since the first answer came really fast, so by the time I realized that my question was horrible, I couldn't delete it.

So, there is a matter of fairness here in mind, my very best answer was just gone *(with no explanation)*, where my very worst question *(which I struggled to delete)* is still alive.

Note that I remember that the user of the question deleted was a user with less than 1000 reputation, so s/he couldn't delete the answer on his own. "This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation." I also remember that it was marked as duplicate.

WOW, the question is opened! :D That's the best thing that could happen and I wouldn't have even think of that! I would like to thank all the people that took the time to read my question here! :)

It's really important for me that the community listened to what I had to say. As for the merge, I am going to delete my other answer and notify the users of answers of the other question (see the answer of this question).

P.S. - Happy new year :)

Comment: Marked as a duplicate, yes, sure.  But deleted? I'm not a participant in the `[c]` tag community but deletion seems odd for this question. The duplicate links are intended as signposts and shouldn't normally be deleted.

Comment: If this was in a tag I participate in I would vote to undelete, but I would like to see discussion from some `[c]` people.

Comment: Looks like a good answer.  If it doesnt get undeleted, I might consider adding it as an answer to the dupe linked.  At the least, you might want to copy the content before it [just disappears](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276508/1070452) given the effort that went into it (it has pictures!).

Comment: My guess would be that people were voting to delete as they felt the question had an "undeserved" number of votes. There is no other logical reason why that should be deleted and the very similar duplicate survives. Voting to undelete.

Comment: @MartinSmith you mean that the question had many upvotes? I can't see the question. Plutonix, yes, I draw the picture when I was in the bus, returning from uni and then I sat at the computer to make it more clear and edited the answer numerous times, until it was good enough IMHO. I don't know what is the dupe link. :P

Comment: Yes the question is on +34.

Comment: @MartinSmith, but isn't that non-democratic? I mean you say that there are people that believe that it has an undeserved number of votes, but what about those 34 people that thought that this was a good question?

Comment: @G.Samaras - I agree. It's only speculation unless one of the delete voters explains but I have seen that sentiment expressed on meta elsewhere recently. And the question does appear fundamentally very similar to the dupe and not actively harmful in some way that would warrant deletion and wiping out the efforts of the answers to me.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the answer. I wish I could vote too! Now I also see what is a "dupe", it is a duplicate I guess! :)

Comment: That a question has many upvotes is taken into account by the system. I don't remember the exact math but it takes one more deletion vote (above the minimum 3 required) per X number of upvotes. The question being discussed here required 7 deletion votes before it was deleted.

Comment: 7 < 34. But I understand that the opinion of some users counts more. @Louis do you think that it should be closed?

Comment: @G.Samaras - It should be *closed* as a duplicate. But closed <> deleted. Especially if it has valuable content in answers.

Comment: Oh yes correct Martin. @Louis I meant deleted.

Comment: @MartinSmith FWIW [question timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26716255/timeline "see events dated Nov 3 '14") shows that it has quickly gotten 3 answers, which pushed it into [meta-tag:hot-questions] (not because it's spectacular mind you, simply because that's [how formula works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/165773)). Anomalous (up)voting in hot network questions is a routine thing, no wonder that tag regulars could consider number of votes "undeserved"

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I undeleted that question and reopened it.  I also marked the other older question as a duplicate and merged it into the question you answered.

I did this because the question you answered had 4x as many views and votes as the other, even though it was only asked a few months ago.

More importantly, I did it because your answer was a really good answer.

Comment: There's going to be some confusion created by the merge, since while the information content of both questions was identical, the particulars of the code (and therefore the analysis) differ.

Comment: Thank you very much George. @BenVoigt is correct. The question there uses `fork() && (fork() || fork());`, while the other question uses `fork() && fork() || fork();` which are different. I could comment the answers that are of the other question, or make an edit to them, mentioning which piece of code they explain. I wait for guidance (then I will delete my (almost) duplicate answer).

Comment: It is possible to undo the merge? Leaving 2 answers there with different context on the same question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: And this is why I don't merge anything but reposted questions.

Comment: @G.Samaras Your best bet would be to edit the answer. Or delete it if you feel like you should.

Comment: @nhahtdh Not really.  In this case; the closer/deleters wanted it both ways: either it's an *exact* duplicate with no new information (and thus one should be merged to the other), or it isn't, in which case it should never have been Deleted. The easiest path is to edit any incorrect information out, or edit it to take into account that extra `fork()`.

Comment: @BoltClock Unfortunately, members of the community took it upon themselves to delete useful information;  not much we can do to keep it from happening except merge it.

Comment: I'm frowning in the general direction of the delete voters there. Come on, people.

Comment: @BradLarson Yeah, I also find the idea of *"undeserved" number of votes* mentioned by Martin to be a toxic concept, people should not be making close/delete decisions based on some measure of how deserving of votes a question or answer is.

Comment: " I also marked the other older question as a duplicate and merged it into the question you answered." Isn't this like cloning your brother and then killing off the original because you like the clone better? I've saw enough sci-fi to know you are never allowed to favour the clone and always have to save the original.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker , why it has been merged. I was the one who asked the original Question and it covers few more aspect of C(like associativity of logical operators). I believe Karols' answer is very much complete.If possible please undo the merge .