# A little consistency in flag reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, link-only-answers

There are pages and pages of questions here about how to correctly and incorrectly flag answers as "not an answer" - which itself to me kind of suggests that that whole process needs some love - and I'm still struggling to really understand what constitutes a worthwhile flag, particularly when the reasons to flag an answer differ from the reasons to accept that flag in the review queue.

I flagged two answers on the same question yesterday which are almost completely identical. In their entirety, they are:

> [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204360/whats-the-term-for-design-ala-object-method1-method2-method3/204366#204366)

And

> It's [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204360/whats-the-term-for-design-ala-object-method1-method2-method3/204373#204373).

Now, in some sense that's literally an answer because the question was "What is the term for...?" and the accepted answer is incorrect anyway. But as a link-only answer, especially when the link isn't even that great (both linked to the same reference), that's pretty weak. Regardless, these two are clearly equivalent *quality* answers - and yet my flag for the first answer was considered helpful and the flag for the second answer, which had the benefit only of a pronoun and a verb and could have been edited in, is disputed. Should these answers have been flagged? Should the flags have been accepted? Is this Yet Another NAA Question? Can I propose YANAAQ as a tag?

Comment: I disagree that those are link-only answers. Stripping away that link and it's still an answer - _what's the term...._ - answer is _method-chaining_.  Now for the flags - they both went into the review queue and were processed by the community which means a variety of people either agreed or disagreed with your original assessment. If I saw those flags, I would have declined both of them.

Comment: At this point, "consistency" in NAA flag reviews is going to be all but a pipe dream now, because the first people to see NAA flags now are the wide diversity of users participating in the review queues, not moderators.

Comment: @bluefeet And yet, a reason to recommend deletion in the review queue is simply "This is a link-only answer (and not spam)." That is clearly true of both of these answers. While you may intend that to mean answers that are just "Check [this] out", that's not what that says - perhaps improve the wording?

Comment: You say that @Bolt, but I'm still seeing a mod as the second delete vote on posts I've flagged as NAA a significant percentage of the time. I want to say at least 50% but it's too much effort to work it out. Between mods and [Soner Gönül](http://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%C3%B6n%C3%BCl) it's probably 80% :-).

Comment: @Barry My point is those are not link-only answers.  If you strip away the link they point the asker to an answer to the question.  As [George](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284269/426671) points out, the issue is the question, not the answers.  Which should be downvoted, edited, etc but not flagged as NAA.

Comment: @bluefeet Those are **absolutely** link-only answers. By definition. They are answers that contain only a link. The fact that you consider a meaningful title in a link as sufficient to surpass your definition of the "link-only" barrier does not change the meaning of those words.

Comment: @Barry Actually no, they aren't link-only answers, reading [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) explicitly states that _if you strip the markup_ you technically have an answer.  As I said, not a great one, but it is still an answer that shouldn't be flagged as NAA.

Comment: @bluefeet Actually, words mean something. Reading that tells me that you still considers some link-only answers to be valid [if potentially low-quality] answers. It doesn't tell me that they aren't link-only answers.

Comment: @Barry http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer#comment736388_225371

Comment: @Barry, "link-only answer" does *not* mean "an answer that consists of only content within an <a> tag". It means "has absolutely nothing but a URL [that is effectively opaque to the reader]".

Comment: ... where have you got the idea that these would be link-only answers? This is an exact example when they're not - they are perfectly valid answers even without the link. I don't see the point of you arguing everybody else just because you've chosen to have a different definition than the rest of the world. However, I do agree on the point that the two examples are pretty much equal to each other - both your flags should have been declined.

Comment: @eis Seriously? Answers being valid and answers being link-only are, in terms of language, orthogonal concepts. They *may be* valid answers, but they *still are* link-only. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is a link. [Definition of Hyperlink](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperlink). That is a link. It is a link-only sentence. Adding descriptive text is obviously good, but it doesn't somehow make it more than just a link. I have nothing against saying that "link-only answers that have ancillary descriptive text" are valid, but you really do need that second part.

Comment: [appropriate link](http://commonsenseatheism.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/head-asplode.png) at this point.

Comment: @Barry a link does not equal link only. When I have only a link, there is no additional information, say [link to google](http://www.google.com). If I'm adding there more information, It's still a link, but it's not link only: [sky is blue](http://www.google.com). When I strip the link from former, there is no information left. I can strip the link from the latter, and still have the text contain information. This means it is not link only. (Yes, seriously.) I really don't understand your viewpoint.

Comment: Furthermore, answers are link-only if they have nothing but a reference to an off-site resource.  "Your answer is on page 77 of Great Programming Styles by Won Gud Koder" is a link-only answer.  So are URLs in code blocks.  "Link" as used here means "connection" and has absolutely nothing to do with clickability.  The markup for a hyperlink has two parts: the text and the link.  The text does not cease to be text just because it has been associated with a link.

Answer (score 33):

Ah, "Link Only".

What does it mean?

Would it surprise you to know it means different things to different people?

1: This is a 'link only' answer:

> [https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Method+chaining&spell=1](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Method%20chaining&spell=1)

2: This is considered by some people to be a 'link only' answer:

> [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

3: But so is this:

> [I think this will help you out.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

Only the second one would be an "OK" answer to the question asked.  The others would need to be edited or deleted (as appropriate).

If an 'answer' (I use that term very loosely) consists of no information when you strip away the link, then it should be edited, flagged, or deleted (in that order).

In the answers you flagged, they contained information when you stripped away the link -- and more than that, *they answered the question that was asked*.

The problem isn't with the answers, it's with the question.

Also, this is a 6 year old question -- unless there's a really compelling reason, it's more useful to spend your time flagging and editing new questions that come in.  That's where we really need your help.

Comment: Shouldn't we be trying to clean up the old material that people keep citing as examples? If one answer is entirely a dup of another (as these are), shouldn't one be deleted? Now that there is a better answer there that completely supersedes them (name and example), shouldn't both be deleted?

Comment: @MichaelT In a perfect Stack Overflow world, there'd be no duplication; but we've got a long way to go for that to be the case.  In this case; the community decided these answers should stay, and our current moderator stance concurs with that assessment.  The power to delete is the power to tell someone we don't want their content.  That's a powerful statement for a moderator to make; that's why we take great care in exercising that power.

Comment: "This is considered by some people..." I mean, it *definitely is* a link-only answer. It is an answer that contains only a link. Maybe the cause for the confusion is that you are trying to add a different meaning onto that phrase (i.e. an answer that contains a link with no ancillary description)

Comment: And when someone [takes the time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278631/why-was-my-flag-on-duplicating-answers-declined/278632#comment126568_278632) to move the material into one, better answer that makes the other two supurfulus, what is the proper course of action for flagging? Or should one try to muster sufficient down votes so 20k users can delete vote it (or have it auto flag to the vlq queue?)? The key is consistently.

Comment: @MichaelT Yes; you should. I'm not going to remove someone's reputation or their answer just because there's duplicate information out there -- that's not for me to do (and it's a silly thing to waste moderator time on, since we don't scale).  If it really upsets you, get together 20 of your closest Stack Overflowers and have at it.  Just don't ask a moderator to do it because it's very low on our list of priorities.  We've got too much to worry about without worrying about duplication in the 'verse.

Comment: Imaginary internet points are imaginary. Shouldn't site quality be more important? Aren't high scoring deleted posts grandfathered for reputation loss when deleting? (If so, waiting for 10 more people to down vote the answers will cause more rep loss than you doing it now)? I thought that mods were concerned about vote mustering from chat or meta - which you now appear to be endorsing.

Comment: @MichaelT If you'd like to have an extended discussion about this, let's go to chat.

Comment: I'm currently scheduled for several hours of meetings (yea employment!) and cannot get to chat from here. If it is still an open offer on about 12h...

Comment: @MichaelT I'll be up. Ping me and I'll let you know my availability.

Comment: @MichaelT - Imaginary points or not, people get really angry when we do these kinds of cleanup operations: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246694/135615 and delete highly voted answers. Not saying that prevents us from doing so, just wanted to point that out.

Comment: @BradLarson I wasn't *mad*, I was just *disappointed*. #stuffdadssay

Comment: @MichaelT: I've never seen any mods object to vote canvassing on chat or elsewhere (although, if some do, I'd certainly like to hear about it). As someone who came to SE from Wikipedia, where such things are [very much frowned upon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Canvassing), it still feels a bit uncomfortable to me even after several years here, but apparently the culture here is just different (and, indeed, a "vote" on SE isn't really the same thing as a "vote" on Wikipedia, anyway).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The "lets get votes" is often seen as part of the meta effect, and previously moderators have proposed [locking questions that are mentioned on meta or in chat](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269191/289086) to try to prevent specific questions being targeted by the meta effect. Intentionally getting people to down vote things from meta or chat would seem to be something that is covered by that question and thus discouraged by the mods who support it. I do know on other SEs, where quality standards are different, vote canvasing in chat is used to help get delete votes in place.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The 'meta effect' is only a problem when the mob mentality is clearly wrong. Like in this instance: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281729/my-top-answer-was-deleted-and-my-worst-question-is-still-not-deleted/281733#comment137348_281733