# Is canvassing for deletion votes on questions with good content OK?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

A now off-topic yet highly voted question that had been closed for three years, was deleted a few days ago. It had a well-maintained community wiki answer (disclaimer: I'm one of the main contributors to that answer).

I've raised the question on meta and two moderators (George Stocker and animuson) pitched in, undeleted the question and put a wiki-lock on it:

[Did we really have to delete this 80-vote community wiki answer after three years?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286966/did-we-really-have-to-delete-this-80-vote-community-wiki-answer-after-three-year)

> Say it with me: We do not delete good content. We do not delete good content.

-- [George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/1269037)

The interesting part is how [that](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/200284/revisions) question [and](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18414012/revisions) others [like](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/902038/revisions) it ended up being deleted. Those who voted to delete include some of the same users again and again for each question: [LittleBobbyTables](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334849/littlebobbytables), [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s), [Yu Hao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009479/yu-hao), [Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%c3%b6n%c3%bcl).

(Side note: As George [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286966/did-we-really-have-to-delete-this-80-vote-community-wiki-answer-after-three-year#comment159819_286970), we should "apply more community pressure to not delete good content". How can we do that?)

After looking in the chatrooms, it turns out that several users have made a habit out of asking for delete votes, e.g.
[hakre](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls&user=367456) (1000+ requests), [cryptic ツ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls&user=1592648),
[NullPoiиteя](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls&user=1723893),
[Second Rikudo aka madara-uchiha aka Truth](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls&user=871050),
[Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls&user=1348195),
[Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls&user=208809) and others.

While notifying other community members of content needing attention is perfectly acceptable, **canvassing** done with the intention of influencing the outcome of a discussion in a particular way compromises the normal consensus decision-making process and introduced bias. The phrasing of the ["delv-pls" tag](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls) in Chat, while convenient and necessary, isn't exactly neutral.

A similar community process when it comes to deletion is that of Wikipedia. There, [canvassing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Canvassing) (including [campaigning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Canvassing#Campaigning) and [vote stacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Canvassing#Votestacking)) are considered inappropriate:

> This page in a nutshell: When notifying other editors of discussions, keep the number of notifications small, keep the message text neutral, and don't preselect recipients according to their established opinions. Be open!

What is our policy on canvassing, and how can we prevent bias and encourage neutrality? (Assuming of course that these are goals within the policy.)

Comment: Only so many users have the ability to cast delete votes in the first place. Only so many of those are interested in using the ability. It is perfectly natural that the same names will show up. How else do you think review should be solicited for delete votes? You seem to have gone from "George Stocker says my answer shouldn't have been deleted" to "there's a delete vote conspiracy" without any middle steps. (And George's answer is far from unanimously approved.)

Comment: On the other hand, we've been told by mods that the way to get material deleted is to canvas for votes either in meta or chat rather than use flags to try to have the mods delete it.  Note [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284267/a-little-consistency-in-flag-reviews/284269#comment146277_284269) with the suggestion from a mod "If it really upsets you, get together 20 of your closest Stack Overflowers and have at it." which specifically endorses/suggests down vote canvasing to effect the deletion of content. ...

Comment: ... Either we have canvasing for votes (down, close, delete), especially to handle content that has a vote threshold above some minimum, or we have mods who act (rather than decline) on flags. If the answer is "neither" then there is a significant amount of moderation and cleaning of poor material that cannot be done.

Comment: I think a better idea would be to make a review queue for recently deleted posts with more than X upvotes. That at least puts some auditing on the otherwise silent deletions of popular posts.

Comment: @Mysticial there *is* the recently deleted list in the 10k tools.  As long as that isn't done when the roomba job runs, all non-self deletes (and deletes from account deletion) do show up there in a timely and not scrolling *too* fast manner. Otherwise, there's on the order of 36k deleted posts from moderators and users each year, or 3000/month which is a nice 100/day. Given the smaller pool of people and the difficulty to get reviews done *otherwise*, would this help at all? or is it just Lance's dream?

Comment: @dan Being a 20k+ user with speedy delete votes on another SE, how many of those 'delete vote please' values are for questions that are on the *same* day to effect a speedy cleanup of poor or unsalvageable material? What is the average reputation and age of a sample of delete vote requests when the votes were canvased?

Comment: @MichaelT The 10k tools feed is (rightly) flooded with posts that deserve to be deleted. You'd have to be really bored to be trawling that list. I'm only suggesting that posts with a significant amount of votes go through "extra auditing" before they do get deleted. Sure, it takes more votes to delete massive upvoted questions, but it says nothing about how many people *don't* want it deleted.

Comment: What Wikpedia does or says is totally irrelevant here, because this isn't Wikipedia. It takes multiple high-rep (10K+) users to vote for deletion in the first place, and there is a recently deleted list in 10K tools where other users can review (and reverse) that deletion. The guidelines for deletion seem already pretty well established, and there is a review process in place that allows others to disagree and reverse the process. As far as your *short list of characters*, how many users do you think have the delete privilege and actually use it? (And yes, I'm one of those who does so.)

Comment: There's so many really bad content off topic questions that need to be deleted that I don't see why users should single out already closed off topic questions that have pretty great content. So in other words, go after the more obvious crap instead of the possible crap that could really just be some useful mud.

Comment: @Roombatron5000: So what do you do when you encounter (however you got there) a question you think should be deleted? Bookmark it for later to go back to? Ignore it even though you think it should be deleted? In other words, ignoring what you think is bad content in order to look for other bad content is simply not a viable solution. If you're voting to delete it in the first place, you clearly already consider it content that should be deleted. It's not a matter of *singling anything out* - it's a matter of voting to delete bad content **when you see it**.

Comment: Your numbers for "delv-pls" are widly misleading.  The user with the most of them requests on average, probably about 3 a month.  The others are a lot less frequent. I don't see this as canvassing.  I see this as a request to help clean crap up when it's identified.

Comment: @Makoto I have no idea how you looked at [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls&User=367456&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) and arrived at "about 3 a month".

Comment: @ivarni:  More or less a SWAG.  Look at the dates that these comments occur on.  There's swells of activity in January, March, and May, but the rest of the year is comparatively quiet.  I could be wildly off, but it just doesn't seem that dire to me.

Comment: @ivarni: I also can't say for certain that any of those links are things that are of value, but this is maybe the third time in almost as many years that I've heard of 10K+ users wantonly attacking questions that are perceived to be "good".

Comment: @Makoto Wether the questions are "good" or not isn't relevant. You can't look at a search result that reports 1073 hits since january 2012 and say "yeah that looks like 3 a month on average". **That** would be wildly misleading.

Comment: @ivarni:  At that point we get into the weeds and the thick of things and a lot of investigation that is time consuming and not entirely constructive.  Yes, averaging that out gives you about 29 per month, but there are some wicked outliers in that data.  Not just that, but you can't tell me that those questions are of any worth to the site.  The **whole point** to that graphic was to suss out the fact that users were intentionally looking for good posts to delete, which just isn't the case.  What I'm saying is that the statistic itself is misleading.  It's really *not* 29 requests per month.

Comment: For the record, I can't tell you either; I'd have to click on all 1,073 of them.  But I have slightly more constructive things to do than that right now.

Answer (score 18):

So this is something at least a few moderators have been discussing lately, because we've been getting flags about a series of high-profile deletions involving the same 3-5 users. It might be valuable to have a longer-form discussion about this on Meta, so I'm going to present a few examples and my own thoughts on the matter.

I should start by saying that I tend to come down on the side of not deleting content that has any value at all, even if it is off topic. I have no problem with closing questions that don't belong, but deleting closed questions with great answers has always been something [I've disagreed with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123179/why-was-this-useful-question-about-app-costs-deleted/123186#123186).

Having said that, the last time someone at SE checked on this, I was the #3 all-time user in delete votes cast on Stack Overflow. There's a lot of pure garbage that comes through here on a regular basis, and looking at the number of delete votes cast isn't a great indicator of someone's attitude toward types of content.

While I sometimes think that certain chatrooms can be a little harsh in the way that they swoop down to downvote and vote to delete certain things, in general their calls for delete votes tend to come on content that deserves it. I reviewed the delete vote history for many of the users involved and found that the vast majority of the questions they voted to delete were heavily downvoted and closed questions with no answers. There was little to preserve in those questions.

So we're not necessarily talking about the process of coordinating delete votes in chatrooms for things, but what those delete votes are being directed towards. Over the last few months we've been getting a series of flags (and been seeing Meta posts like yours) about highly voted closed questions with good answers being deleted, and noticed the same names over and over again. That's what I'd like to talk about.

I apologize for singling out specific people, but the only way to do this is to present examples. Here is a sample list of some deleted but strongly upvoted questions (a few now undeleted in response to flags) that came up in a recent query of delete votes by one group of people:

- [What does AngularJS do better than jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery)
- [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902038/lua-vs-other-scripting-languages
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123494/whats-your-favourite-irb-trick
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296618/what-is-the-most-common-use-of-the-trie-data-structure
- [Magic in C++ with this expression x = y - x + (y = x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671520/magic-in-c-with-this-expression-x-y-x-y-x)
- [Stop on first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474526/stop-on-first-error)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075920/heroku-in-real-life-apps
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310851/what-is-the-use-of-dual-table-in-oracle
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174131/looking-for-a-good-programmable-java-cms-content-management-system
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139684/delphi-free-and-open-source-components-that-are-still-maintained
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954164/choosing-between-java-and-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450399/which-java-yaml-library-should-i-use
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363052/best-weather-apis-free-for-commercial-use
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547849/good-examples-of-python-docstrings-for-sphinx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714501/python-torrent-library
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971/what-is-the-best-resource-you-know-to-learn-dojo
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775049/good-looking-programs-that-are-built-using-wxpython-for-their-ui
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540047/is-the-c-language-really-outdated
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243049/what-do-you-think-about-pythons-new-set-literal-2-7a3
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636508/elasticsearch-as-a-database
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628830/netbeans-tips-and-tricks
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522/tips-for-learning-elisp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809/javascript-unit-testing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826458/hidden-features-of-qt
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison

The first question is: does the community even have a problem with questions like this being deleted?

A few years ago we had a large argument on Meta about moderators deleting highly-voted questions in response to flags. At the time, it was impractical for many of these highly-voted questions to be deleted by the community because of the huge number of delete votes that took. Therefore, moderators were being used as proxies to remove these via flags. People objected to a number of high-profile deletions and went after specific moderators about them. That culminated in [the delete vote requirements being lowered and moderators backing away from deleting questions like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity).

This seemed to be a compromise that appealed to both sides. The tools were given to regular users to take action on things without involving moderators, and you're free to vote how you want. Deletions like this could be seen as a consequence of that.

However, this assumes that people are voting based on reviewing the merits of each thing they see. I'm beginning to be concerned that this is not the case, and that a group of users is hanging out in [the old 10k tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) and blindly casting delete votes on everything that appears there.

Again, is this a problem? I don't know. The fact is, we don't have great tools for reviewing recently deleted content, since so much trash comes through that the "recently deleted" list is all but useless. Once these questions are deleted, it's not very likely that they'll be noticed again to be undeleted. I wanted to at least present this to the community, along with my own opinion that I don't think many of these should have been deleted, but I don't know if any action is warranted here or not.

Comment: "A few years ago we had a large argument on Meta about moderators deleting highly-voted questions in response to flags." HAS IT REALLY BEEN ALMOST THREE YEARS

Comment: Given the relatively small number of users who cast large amounts of delete votes, and the variety of questions that get deleted, I doubt these people have enough time to properly read through the answers, or sufficient specific domain knowledge to appreciate the value of the answer ([example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286966/did-we-really-have-to-delete-this-80-vote-community-wiki-answer-after-three-year#comment160328_286970) from a few hours ago).

Comment: I really want to reply to this answer in general, because there's a lot of...how should I put it..."crap" in that list.  Stuff that shouldn't really be saved.  Stuff that should be moved into a duplicate question (if one exists for the aforementioned question).  *Maybe* a question in regards to this particular subject could be formulated?

Comment: @Makoto - Possibly. I was going to ask something like this as a question, to poll the thoughts of the community on it, and this came up. I think it's worth talking about, and an answer might not be the best place for it. I left many of these deleted because I didn't feel strongly enough to override community votes, but I saw value in many of them. I wanted to at least use them as a starting point for discussion.

Comment: It sounds like a very useful tool would be a "recently deleted with +2 score" list, to find deleted potential gems.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the meaning behind what we do, which is understandable because it can come across as confusing to outsiders.

When I post [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) in chat (or [delv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delv-pls), or even the rarer [review-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review-pls) and even [reopen-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-pls)), I don't *ask* anyone to cast their close votes. Not by a long shot. I'm posting a question on chat that needs attention of some kind.

I'm posting a question that *I think* should be closed. I never told anyone to act based on my conclusions. What [whatever-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatever-pls) means is "Hey! There's a question here that needs attention. Read it and act (or don't)". The difference better [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) and [delv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delv-pls) is merely categorial.

My priority is the quality of posts on the site. And [cv-ring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-ring) came to solve a problem, the problem where things are not dealt with fast enough. I don't care for the people involved, or even the topic discussed, when I determine whether or not I should vote to close. I only value the quality of the post at hand.

Comment: I dunno, the use of the word "pls" seem to imply the imperative mood.

Comment: The word `pls` implies that action is required. Not necessarily that I ask you to cv. The idea was to keep it short and sweet. "look-pls" might have been a better term, but we also wanted to rely what we expected the final outcome would be. It's not an ideal system, and it can get very opinionated at times. But its success rate is pretty good.

Comment: I have a suggestion: just go with "pls" ;)