# Deleted Question too broad!

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

This question:

[Memory Leak Detectors Working Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446850/memory-leak-detectors-working-principle)

Was voted to close and then deleted as being too broad.
OK the question could be considered very broad but the accepted answer provides a very good answered and provides useful information (we do we want to loose this by deleting the question).

Personally I would vote to unclose if I had spotted the close previously. But before I go and click on undelete is there something I am missing that I should be taking into consideration?

Comment: I voted undelete. Yes it's broad, but I don't see why it needs to be deleted. My view is the same as Brad Larson's here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287062/922184

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flag a question for protection](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287132/how-to-flag-a-question-for-protection)

Comment: I pushed the fifth button and mentioned question is no longer on hold.

Comment: @Braiam OP is, by no mean, asking how to protect questions from deletion, but asks why particular question was deleted. How can question, that asks about general rules (flagging all questions for protection) be a duplicate of a question that asks about one particular situation? I think you misunderstood the whole picture here.

Comment: @trejder read past the title, he's asking why a question that was deleted wasn't "protected" (aka locked) instead and what steps should he follow so there isn't any danger to being deleted (or opportunities to be undeleted). Remember that duplicates on meta are more loosy.

Answer (score 14):

There were a handful of pretty crappy answers posted - two of them bordering on spam. Folks gently encouraged the author of one to improve, another to delete and the third was forcibly deleted, so the issue seems to be resolved - however, I can see how it might've left a bad taste.

I think we can give it another go, keeping an eye on further answers as-needed - however, I've protected the question to discourage drive-by answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "deleted as being too broad". People should not be abusing the delete button like this.

The entire point of putting questions on hold is to prompt the OP into improving them. Then the re-open queue system kicks in.

None of this works if the question was summarily deleted. It is not spam so it should be undeleted.

Comment: There were a bunch of "pretty crappy answers" to that question, how you propose to fix them?

Comment: @Braiam: If you find an answer that you think is "crappy", downvote it. What more do you want? Who decides what it means to "fix" an answer? You? What gives you the power of absolute judgement?

Comment: How can I downvote something that should *just be deleted*, as they already are?

Comment: @Braiam: Your assertion that "they should just be deleted" is false. You have the wrong idea about what deletion is for. I already touched upon why that is, in my previous comment. If you disapprove of a post, _downvote it_. It is the collection of your opinion, _along with everybody else's opinion_ (this is the core point that you are forgetting) that results in a positive or negative net post score. That is how Stack Exchange works. You should really know this by now.

Comment: You seemly aren't reading *anything*, are you? **[They where deleted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287909/792066)** by the poster or the community. Clearly those crappy answers should have been deleted, downvotes notwithstanding.

Comment: @Braiam: Oh so just because some people deleted the question, it _should_ have been deleted? What sort of nonsense logic is that? Goes along with your "I disagree therefore you are not reading anything" logic. Come back calmer.

Comment: I believe that you have a fundamental problem... re-read everything Shog and I have said and find the common points, and summarize them in your mind, then admit how misleading you were.

Comment: @Braiam: You have a fundamental problem: your rudeness.

Answer (score -6):

Personally I love those kinds of questions and many of my bookmarked favorites fit in that category. They are uber broad. Asking how to implement a leak detector in general is so, so broad. Might as well ask how to implement an operating system while we're at it.

But they are a type of bait that can sometimes lure some expert answers very unique to this site if we're lucky. Of course they could also yield junk.

Yet sometimes they yield pearls. It's like if someone asks how Doom 3 was implemented in the laziest, broadest kind of way, there might be some off-chance that John Carmack himself writes an answer and then we have a magnificent pearl. And that type of pearl is so magnificent in ways where no question posting an MCVE of broken code can ever rival. I found a similar broad question on gamedev asking how Dangerous Dave implemented the scrolling on such limited hardware (Apple II) where John Romero actually appeared to make a quick account just to write an answer on how the tiling worked where he also wrote about how it was all done in 6502 and how it was tricky for EGA graphics in the DOS version.

And in the few times I get to write a very detailed answer given my narrow and limited expertise that challenges me to really think of how to answer it well that combine all my years of experience in that one area where I happen to have some experience, it's usually a very broad question. For example, I have yet to encounter questions asking about the intricacies of implementing a production renderer to give me an excuse to write about it. But I have encountered some very basic questions like how to implement a raytracer where I can find an excuse to share my experiences. And I like sharing my experiences as a learning process predominantly, not a teaching one, since putting my thoughts and experiences out there might invite people who teach me better ways to deal with the problems. I'm kind of validating my own experiences through the process of attempting such answers.

I like them even if the site doesn't. That said, I'm still probably a misfit on SO. I tend to find I resonate more with Software Engineering which allows more of those kinds of questions to some degree, but I haven't really found a "home" for finding those kinds of detailed experienced answers which often require a either a sufficiently broad question on many people's minds if it's asked by someone without much experience, or an extremely advanced question by someone which often has the risk of turning into a tumbleweed because only people who have poured years into the exact same problem can answer those ultra advanced questions, so they tend to barely get any views and get lost in the shuffle.

Anyway, one thing I'm always wondering about is whether the question or the answer is more important. Since that question has fortunately been kept open and protected. But it obviously violates the guidelines. But these exceptions often make me wonder what the site really wants. If I go by community guidelines I'd downvote that question and vote to close as OT again. But I love the answers too much.

Comment: I think we'd all prefer to see fewer "MCVEs of broken code" and more thoughtful questions for experts to answer, but there's a balance to be struck. Too-broad questions in my experience are just as likely to attract not-useful three liners that provide equally broad "pointers". And then it's not much better than [finding that long-dead forum thread](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's a tough one and naturally I don't have a good overview of the site content and all the bad stuff that gets through, since I don't participate much in moderation (I'm more interested in looking for interesting answers and trying my best to write some of my own and learning through that process).  Mostly I just have a pipe dream of seeing more and more interesting answers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Sometimes I think that gamble is worth it though as far as the "sand quality" can go, since those pearly answers are few and far between. Then again I might just be compromising my standards too much. In my case I work in a very specialized area of visual FX software for films and so forth. I generally don't find many people working in the same trenches, even on the Computer Graphics site. So often if I get any excuse to share some of my deeper production-level experiences in this field, I have to settle for something very basic/broad like, "How do raytracers work?"

Comment: @JoshCaswell My dream would be to find peers working on similar problems: code gen for shaders like those in OpenSL, nodal networks for visual shader programming and the design choices associated, optimization techniques like SIMD ray packets, using hybrid GPU/CPU rendering passes, generalizing rendering buffers for compositing, etc. I would be ecstatic to find such questions, even more to find answers to them besides my own.  But mostly I just find a lot of questions about, say, broken linked list implementations which were likely CS101 assignments. Then basic/broad questions seem wonderful.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thinking about this more, I think one of the problems is that maybe professionals are shy to ask questions. At least I imagine there are some other people out there working professionally on VFX software, but the majority of questions I find are from hobbyists or researchers or students. So often it's difficult to find the kind of question that invites professionals to share their knowledge and experiences, at least in the areas I'm looking at, unless someone just asks something very basic like "how do leak detectors work?" But I feel like the site is kind of broken for [...]

Comment: @JoshCaswell [...] advanced topics when those types of basic/broad questions which might at least have some chance of inviting a professional answer seem far more likely to be targeted for closing than, say, the endless homework questions from students struggling to understand how pointers work in C or C++... which simply doesn't give much room for a professional answer besides, "you're accessing a dangling pointer. I recommend picking up a good book on how C works."

Comment: The main exception for me is optimization-related topics, typically low-level. There I still find many experts. And that hits a very general level of interest I have since things like physics engines and raytracers are performance-critical, but it's kind of the exception in my case. Though that's what drew me to SO originally was people like Mysticial who had such expert knowledge on computer architecture, and I learned so much from his answers accumulated from years of experience (in ways I didn't learn from other places). But I'm hungry for more of those in other areas than optimization.

Comment: I believe the reason optimization questions sometimes invite world-class answers is because the site favors the MCVE. A lot of MCVEs will often just be broken code from people struggling to understand APIs or languages who didn't take the time to thoroughly read the docs. But MCVEs related to performance can invite computer architecture wizards who can break down the disassembly, profile it, analyze the cache misses branch mispredictions, and provide amazing answers. But the other main case besides that is simply, "How do leak detectors work?"

Comment: I think there's definitely a (perverse?) natural filter in that good, interesting questions are _hard_ to ask. For myself I know that I don't want to take someone else's time unless a) I'm sure I can't figure it out, and b) I can clearly and succinctly present relevant info. Whereas throwing up some broken code takes no time. I personally think the best way to encourage more good interesting questions is to equalize the cost of the less good ones; an artificial filter to compensate for the bias of the natural one.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think it's a fundamental problem since most questions will inadvertently be lazy. When most of them are, I'm kind of lowering my standards a lot when I start to see those basic/broad questions as potential pearl baits. But I tend to get really depressed lurking in tags like C and C++ when someone asks something like, "How do people write voxel engines?" which starts to invite a couple of really interesting and experienced answers only to get closed 10 minutes after.... at which point I'm back to looking at questions from people struggling to understand basics with broken code.