# Why was this recommendation question undeleted? Why does it need to stick around?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, undeleted-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430742/is-there-a-free-version-control-server-provider-for-non-public-projects was deleted back in October of 2014 (partly by yours truly), and then undeleted this past February by a single moderator.

If this question were asked today, it would be closed and deleted in a heartbeat.  It's seriously just a list of link-only answers and product recommendations, and the accepted answer looks like this:

> Give a look to :
>
> - SVN
>
>   - [XP-Dev](http://xp-dev.com/) (No longer free)
>   - [OpenSVN](https://opensvn.csie.org/) (No longer available)
>   - [Codebase](http://atechmedia.com/codebase)
>   - [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) (No longer free)
> - Git
>
>   - [XP-Dev](http://xp-dev.com/)  (No longer free)
>   - [Codebase](http://atechmedia.com/codebase)
>   - [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) (No longer free)

Let's see... "No longer free", "No longer available", "No longer free", "No longer free"... I'm seeing a pattern here.

Since I'm apparently part of the "They know who they are, and they know what they're doing" Delete gang, I'm going to try something new:  instead of simply casting another Delete vote and starting the whole silly process over again, I'm going to take this a learning lesson, and simply ask:

> Why was this undeleted?  Why is this question sticking around?  Am I fundamentally misunderstanding what counts as a "Should be closed, but not deleted" question?

Comment: next it'll be getting reopen votes....

Comment: Ain't that the truth

Comment: And we can't vote to delete again because there are duplicates linking to it.

Comment: @Clive - aha, that may be why it was undeleted.  I've seen a bunch of questions undeleted because of dupes leading to them.  If it's a crappy question though, why not just delete the dupes as well, instead of undeleting a bad question?  I guess we'll have to wait and hear from some higher-ups...

Comment: the revisions on the accepted answer are quite funny though - they've almost completely changed the answer over time (still, most of which are useless really). Plus those edits were a while back now, most of the 'available' ones probably aren't available anymore anyway!

Comment: Well, surely you can figure this out yourself, moderators get flagged about this.  It usually takes several un/delete cycles before they get tired of trying to keep everybody happy.  Repeatedly seeing the same names back on these deletions isn't very healthy btw.

Comment: @HansPassant: then just wipe it out? * poof * ?  would sure make me happy knowing one less off topic question isn't posted here... and less of an encouragement to ask similar questions from new users...

Comment: Here is the [query for the dupes](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298080) that point to that question.

Comment: @HansPassant "Repeatedly seeing the same names back on these deletions isn't very healthy btw". I agree.

Comment: @rene don't need a query... just look at the [linked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/430742?lq=1).  As of this comment, only one of them appears to be a duplicate (with one more down vote on it, 20k speedy delete votes can act on that one) - the others are just links in comments or answers.

Comment: @jbutler483 this didn't happen, probably because the guy who undeleted, forgot to edit its title into something "moar useful", like [_Looking for_ a free version control server provider for non-public projects](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282932/839601)

Comment: @gnat: that's even worse :P

Comment: `"Repeatedly seeing the same names back on these deletions isn't very healthy btw". I agree.`  Seriously, if the moderators of Stack Overflow have problems with the way some of the users, myself included, are cleaning up questions, stop making passive-aggressive side-comments and pussyfooting around a potential problem, and *reach out* to the users.  It's that simple.

Comment: I feel this should be asked during the elections...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - I've posted some of my thoughts on this here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286997/is-canvassing-for-deletion-votes-on-questions-with-good-content-ok/287062#287062 . I think George might be referring to that. It's not so much passive-aggressive as we don't like calling out specific people publicly. However, there isn't a great way to have a discussion about this without examples, so I linked to a few there. It's a pattern we had noticed in responding to flags, but I don't know if it's something we should even be concerned about.

Comment: @BradLarson unfortunately, 10k tools are a corse way fix problems with questions that have lots of upvoted poor quality answers. Even 20k users can't delete those. They also can't go and make a wiki lock answer without mod involvement... and the value of the material on the site is questionable. I mention this in [a meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287042/289086).  I just dropped half a dozen custom flags (not going to flag NAA) on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/187587/289086) because, while it was undeleted, the quality of the answers wasn't fixed as part of that process.

Comment: ... such a question would have been a perfect candidate for a wiki lock, but instead it was undeleted with a good chunk the poor quality answers repeating the same links again and again. Unfortunately, this can't be cleaned up by regular users. And undeleting without the associated cleaning can leave a bad taste in the mouths of people who are striving to address the perceived lower quality of questions and answers that Stack Overflow is getting. If moderators could be proactive instead of reactive in fixing these quality issues, it might be a different matter.

Comment: @BradLarson That's exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: @MichaelT: I think your last statement is quite bang out of order. I believe Moderators do their best to do what is best/fair for all users. To say "moderators aren't proactive" really is completely incorrect. Whilst I tend to agree that this question doesn't benefit users, that does not remotely suggest that mods aren't working to improve the site in a way of preventing users from adding 'bad content'.

Comment: @jbutler483 I have *rarely* seen moderators act on poor quality old content without a flag first. There are searches and queries that one can do that will easily find hundreds of such posts, but they leave this up to the community to delete and then undelete and then complain and then act. When [undeleting posts](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/187587/revisions) that have 30+ answers, with the majority of them one liner links and duplicates, there are no deletions as part of that act leaving it up to people to flag them. *That* is what I mean by being proactive.

Comment: @MichaelT: Pray tell, how many mods are there? And how many registered users? Of course more users 'should' be picking up/flagging issues - the ratio is huge! It's already been mentioned they're getting around 2000 flags a day! Catch yourself on and realise that there's only so many hours in a day!

Comment: @jbutler483 there aren't that many... but if you note on the [revision history of that post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/187587/revisions) a mod acted on it already and *certainly* saw the quality of the answers on the post... and ignored that. Instead, I've got 6 flags [and a suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7616041) on various answers there that are duplicates of other answers. Unfortunately, this means that it will likely take *more* work for mods to clean up... but at least they won't have to worry about the technical merits of the posts.

Comment: @MichaelT: On another note; you have just over 1500 rep on SO... Why are you so interested in the capabilities and restrictions of a 10 or even 20k rep'd user?

Comment: @MichaelT There are at least two groups here: The Deletionists; and Those that believe we shouldn't delete off topic content that has a high number of votes/views/etc.  (the exact nature of the latter being up to debate); Where the Deletionists believe we aren't being proactive, the "Keep content" crowd praises our restraint.  It's easy to say "If only the moderators did what I wanted them to do, everything would be great!" without realizing that we have to balance the needs of not only these two groups, but people who visit from Google.

Comment: @jbutler483 I have 36k on Programmers.SE. Many of the issues that Stack Overflow faces are ones that Programmers.SE faces. I've often flagged there to merge, lock, and delete highly voted content that is duplicate of other material. The lack of granularity of the community moderation tools have often made it difficult for me to do it myself without a flag.

Comment: And Vice Versa. When we delete something, the "Keep Content" crowd goes up into a tizzy, and the Deletionists praise us for being "Proactive".

Comment: @GeorgeStocker When you undelete a post without acting to clean up the remained of the question, it says to many users "this is acceptable quality". Do you believe that all of the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/) are acceptable quality for the standards of today's Stack Exchange users? If the answer is "no", why was this not examined in the process of undeleting the post? Given that this was a post that would be a good candidate for a wiki lock, why not just complete that process (something that only mods can do - the community can't)?

Comment: I would also point out that I am not saying delete content. I am saying curate it so that it represents the quality of the site that *you* desire to see - in a way that only you, as a moderator can. Only you can delete upvoted duplicate answers. Only you can put the wiki lock on the post after pulling together all of the remaining content. You were given a diamond with the promise of [cleaning up questions based on your edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-10890701). You have that power now. You have been given tools to do that with the wiki lock since '12.

Comment: It's strange, I genuinely thought I was contributing to the site by helping clean up off-topic questions that were now off-topic, never on-topic in the first place, or could cause confusion in the future.  Getting lumped in with these apparent "Deletionist" and "Keep Content" factions is weird and enlightening at the same time.  I know I can be abrasive at times, but I had (or at least thought I had) Stack Overflow's best intentions in mind.  Maybe I was wrong, maybe I'm *not* contributing, or at least not in a positive fashion.  I dunno... I've got some things to think about...

Comment: That's what everybody says :P (Not discrediting you or anything, you know what I mean.)

Comment: There's even a wikipedia entry [about that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities) which not only includes the one on the post, all of them are easily categorized and easily findable "control verision provider/host"

Comment: @MichaelT - "I have rarely seen moderators act on poor quality old content without a flag first." The thing about that is, if we *do* act on something by ourselves, you wouldn't even see it. I can tell you that I regularly run sweeps for known spam-attracting terms and deal with the questions and answers that no one bothered to flag. Lots of stuff gets missed in review (or misreviewed), and I go back to clean that up. Same with non-answers, vote fraud, patterns of abusive behavior, etc. It's a big site, and I don't think you can say we're not proactive because of a few limited observations.

Comment: If you're talking about why we don't act on the specific off-topic but upvoted questions like this one, that's because we defer to the community on those. The last time we were used as deletion proxies for the community turned into an absolute mess, and led to a change in the way we act on these: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity

Comment: @BradLarson the community already deleted it once. Furthermore, the community doesn't have the tools to delete upvoted duplicate answers or wiki lock. What community moderation actions are you expecting on this question?

Comment: @BradLarson I apparently need to explain my proactive comment more. There is a lot of janitorial work that the average user doesn't see - and you do clean that up, no doubt about it. However, in the area of content quality, the visible actions are that of undeleting a post with poor quality answers and leaving it there - waiting for the community to act on it (which they can't in most cases). When a post is undeleted, it behooves those who participate in that action to *thoroughly* review it, flag the content that needs flags, delete content that should be deleted, and edit where needed.

Comment: ... That this was *not* done when the post was undeleted (and those are silent too - they don't bump the activity) means that it fell on the community to be reactive in the review and curating of the content. If this was done when the post was undeleted, there would have been much less drama around this question.  That that, I give you [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/187587/289086) which one can *now* show that the moderators are willing to curate the material that is undeleted before it blows up as another 'why are my flags declined on this undeleted post with crap answers' meta post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What happened here, from what I can see in the history of this and related questions, was that someone flagged a question that had been closed as a duplicate of this. They stated that the duplicate link had "gone dead", and on looking into it I saw that the target question was highly upvoted and had a number of what looked to me to be good answers.

As a result, I undeleted this question to not leave a dead-end for the questions that were closed as a duplicate of this.

In general, I have a tendency to want to preserve content that others have found useful, even if it isn't a great fit for the site. I thought I saw that here, with a highly-voted (if off topic) question that received what looked like good answers.

However, you make good points about the outdated nature of the answers. If these answers are no longer viable or are misleading, and the question is still present at the top of Google searches, I can see a case being made for deleting it again. I just wanted to preserve any worthwhile content, but if there is no lasting value in this, I have no problem with removing it again.

We may need to find and remove or re-close the duplicates that point to this to get rid of the dead links, though.

Comment: Could you just unlock it, so we could fix it?

Comment: There's already a very through version of this question on [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities). Nobody is actually willing to maintain the list on SO. WP offers a nice table where you can easily compare many of them, why keep it?

Comment: Because George went and cleaned up all the duplicate links to this, and we've given this enough time to debate it here, I've gone ahead and deleted the question. The arguments above seem to be enough to support that.

Answer (score 6):

For questions like these, I begin to wonder if we should just [mirror Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities).  They do a better job of having the community update and maintain lists of links.

If we wish to mirror Wikipedia locally, that seems like a lot of extra work and a violation of DRY principles.

By confusing where to look for this type of information (I look on Wikipedia first for lists of links), it diminishes the brand of Stack Overflow as a Q&A site.

By encouraging these questions (keeping them around), we make it harder for new users to understand the types of questions that should be asked.  By keeping the crap answers (that 20ks can't delete because they are upvoted), it serves as an example for new users of the types of answers we 'want'.

Put the material in the right place, and help users understand how to use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+version+control+software+hosts) to find the proper material in the right spot.

Comment: There's already another resource offering the same service at higher standard [in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities), wouldn't you agree that we are a poor fit for that content and therefore we shouldn't host it?

Comment: @Braiam "Stack Exchange Q&A model has been optimized to only cover topics where Wikipedia falls short (["long tail"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)). It is intended to complement, not to compete against Wikipedia.

There is certain crossover between Stack Exchange and Wikipedia, but it is rather narrow..." ([Is a question that specifically asks for a summary of a broad topic valuable to Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234673/165773))