# Is a self-answer of "looks like I had a typo" really not NAA?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654031/getting-syntax-error-from-if-statement-why) is a standard "missing a `)`" typo question, pretty promptly closed as such. After it was pointed out, the OP [answered his own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654031/getting-syntax-error-from-if-statement-why/34654800#34654800) (deleted, 10k+ only) with just "Question due to typo, case closed." That's the entire answer, verbatim. I flagged it as NAA, and it was declined with "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer." It was deleted *by reviewers* just a few hours after it was posted, one of whom left a boilerplate "this doesn't answer the question" comment.

Is that really not NAA? Why was that flag declined?

[image: Not NAA, deleted as NAA]

Comment: I would think a full answer would at least be: "This was due to a typo: `XyZ` should be `XYZ`". Otherwise I would just answer all questions with "You have a bug", without pointing out where, or how to fix it.

Comment: Why even bother flagging the answer? The OP found out it was a typo and posted an answer to that effect, so vote to close the question accordingly and continue on your merry way?

Comment: Why bother? Because... well, because it was NAA (I thought). And NAA answers should be flagged. So I did. QED.

Comment: Why bother somebody else?  You have plenty of rep to deal with this by yourself.  Downvote, refresh, delete.

Comment: I just got the deletion privilege a couple hours ago. And yes, I did then vote to delete the question about 15 minutes ago.

Comment: I often vote "Looks OK" on similar answers. How else will the Close-Vote reviewers know to close the question as caused by a typo? Far too often, the answer gets deleted within minutes, leaving the question sitting there for ages with a single close vote.

Comment: @Nisse good point.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a duplicate of the linked question, as that one is about answers that are just a link to an answer on a dup question, while this one is about a "thanks I see that the problem was XYZ" that got deleted by reviewers as NAA before my flag was even processed. Seems substantively different to me.

Answer (score 47):

Saying it was a typo is answering the question. **The question wouldn't exist if it wasn't for the typo.** Not saying *what* or where the typo was doesn't change that. All it does is make it unnecessarily difficult for others to find that out for themselves.

But who cares? A one-off typo isn't going to help future readers *anyway*. That's why we close and delete *questions* that arise due to one-off mistakes.

In fairness, I'm not entirely sure how your NAA flag reached the moderator queue in order to be declined by another moderator in the first place considering it was deleted through the review process. I'm guessing the review deletion was effected by a different queue.

Either way, that answer didn't need to be flagged. It's not going to survive the deletion of the question, so just vote to close, and delete, the question and move on.

Comment: I was just wondering why the only person involved who didn't think it was NAA was the mod who declined my flag - with an "it isn't NAA" reason, not a "who cares" reason. Does the flag need to be accurate _and_ catch a mod while they're feeling flaggy? Because I don't know how to arrange the latter.

Comment: The "it isn't NAA" reason is why it was declined. The "who cares" reason is why flagging it was unnecessary to start with.

Comment: So, the other reviewers came to an incorrect conclusion (the same one I did)?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes they did.

Comment: Flagging is like a box of chocolates, I guess.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to investigate why all the reviewers made the same mistake.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Reviewers in the low-quality posts queue tend to be a little too trigger happy in deleting content. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563 is a good read on this topic.

Comment: "The question wouldn't exist if it wasn't for the typo" - if someone gets drunk and posts a question about the broken code they wrote, should they post an answer consisting solely of "lol i was drunk when i posted this q sry" the next morning? After all, the question wouldn't exist if the poster was sober.

Comment: Tiger let it go, bro. Remember that R programming language you were going to master? Put that energy into R.

Comment: What was the children's story about the guy who lived in a rickety old house that kept him up at night? The doctor prescribed a chicken, then a goat, then a horse, etc. After a week the doctor tells the man to get rid of all the farm animals, and the man has a great sleep from then on. I vote to remove the NaA and VLQ flags from the flag dialog for a week, then when they come back everyone would be much more appreciative.

Comment: This answer raises another point. The NAA flag is mistakenly declined a lot for one reason in particular: often, actual answers are posted that don't attempt to answer **THE** question that was asked. The dialogue for the NAA flag says "this does not attempt to answer **the** question" (emphasis mine). Answers that don't address the question above are, by this description, NAA, yet they often get declined because the flag is titled "Not *An* Answer". Since it's not feasible to change the behavior of all flag reviewers, please change "the" in the above sentence to "a" to rectify this problem.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Funny you mention that. We've had a few flags along the lines of "I was drunk" from people on their own questions after the fact - but no NAA self-answers to that effect. Not yet.

Comment: @TylerH: I'm not sure it's any more feasible to change the behavior of all flaggers. If you can change one large, poorly-educated crowd with UI tweaks, surely you can do the same for a smaller, better-educated one, no?

Comment: @NathanTuggy The feature is already on the docket per one of Shog's MSE posts I found a while ago; it's waiting on a UI overhaul for the moderator flags page.

Comment: @TylerH: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Which feature?

Comment: @NathanTuggy sorry, "feature" is the wrong word for how I wrote my comment. He is planning to update the NAA verbiage to something along the lines of "this answer does not address the problem posed by the question"

Comment: @TylerH: OK, so a UI tweak to improve reviewer behavior to match desired and commonly-seen flagging behavior is coming. Sounds good enough.

Comment: I kinda understand your answer @BoltClock. But I need some guidance. So is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35861863/4099593)  an answer, but only a poor one? I am confused to flag and don't want declined flags.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: In that case, the question can still survive without the answer, so the answer should still be flagged, not the question. But since "I went with a different approach" can be seen as an attempt to close the question with an answer, it's unwise to flag it as NAA. If you really want to flag it for review, use VLQ instead - there's a very good chance the Low Quality Posts queue will recommend its deletion.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock I will flag as VLQ.

Answer (score 33):

Since there [are demonstrably no longer any standards for answers on this site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314400/603977)*, I would recommend never again bothering with the "Not an answer" flag. Just [collect a few other 20k-reppers and downvote such posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284267/a-little-consistency-in-flag-reviews/284269#comment146277_284269) until they're delete-able.

"It was a typo" is an answer the same way "Yes." is an answer to "Excuse me, do you have the time?" It's utter crap to say that this is [a useful contribution to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), or that it is ["...even a partial answer to the actual question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). It's a *reply*, like in a forum, those things we're supposed to be better than for getting solutions.

The issue of [the *question* being the true problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314398/603977) is irrelevant from a flagging standpoint, because [per Robert Harvey♦, "Mods *do not look at the question* when moderating 'Not an Answer' flags."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/603977) The answer is *a* problem, and the answer was flagged. It should have been dealt with properly -- by deletion.

(Except...[sometimes mods do consider context?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290370/can-we-please-clear-misunderstanding-that-deleting-old-highly-upvoted-posts-caus#comment178167_290378) In which case the question should have been dealt with *in response to the flag*, whether or not the flag was declined.)

---

*See also: [Using NAA on jokes that make no attempt to answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question/308459#308459)

Comment: I can hardly believe that "screenshot of _The Fifth Element_" wasn't NAA on how to access the fifth element of an array. It's on the same level as "is there anything bigger than the `bignum` class" being answered with "your mom."

Comment: The party-line responses on this issue boggle my mind, @TigerhawkT3.

Comment: Also, your example "`bignum`" -> "your mom" is awesome, and I feel compelled to use it next time I have to write about this.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 In fairness, the flag on the Fifth Element joke was disputed, i.e. at least one user with 10k rep rejected it. It wasn't declined, which would have meant rejected by a ♦ moderator.

Comment: @Gilles you only need 500 rep to review the LQPRQ

Comment: @TinyGiant Oh, right, sorry, I'd misread that thread as being from 2011 when flags worked differently. Now it's 2k (not 500, the LQ queue opens when you can edit).

Comment: @Gilles ah I was under the impression the LQPRQ was lumped in with [first posts and late answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), but it is not. We were both wrong on that one.

Comment: So if I start collecting 20k reppers, is it *repperfarming*? :D

Comment: Mr. Harvey's universal declaration is now incorrect. ;-) Of course, I suppose all that means is that more inconsistency has been introduced into NAA flag processing, which is why we see more questions on Meta than ever before. :-(

Comment: @CodyGray _"Mr. Harvey's universal declaration is now incorrect"_ Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 15):

A post that consists solely of “Question due to typo, case closed.” does not constitute an answer by any reasonable standard. A post that explains where the typo is would be a mediocre answer. A post that explains how to deduce the position and nature of the typo from the error message and other clues would be a good answer. But just saying “there's a typo” doesn't answer the question. It isn't going to help anyone, ever. The fact that it's a correct statement doesn't change this.

A “very low quality” flag would have been better, because those are handled through a review queue before they're shown to mods. (It's a technical difference between “very low quality” and “not an answer”.)

A flag wasn't really necessary in the first place, because the question itself was deletion material. That doesn't make the flag *wrong*, but it does make it somewhat ill-advised. However, there *is* a reason to delete non-answers to closed questions sometimes, which is that [closed questions are automatically deleted under certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) — a single answer with no upvote doesn't prevent deletion, but an upvoted answer or two zero-scoring answers would prevent deletion.

(Note: I'm not a moderator on SO, but I am a moderator on other SE sites. I wouldn't even have hesitated in deleting a comparable answer on the sites I moderate. I'm used to SO moderators being trigger-happy in declining flags on answers, but this case surprises me.)

Comment: We have been told countless times in the past that a VLQ flag is a subset of NaA that should be used for absolute gibberish and nonsense. If your brain cannot parse it as text, use a VLQ flag. The only thing a VLQ flag has over an NaA flag is that, when marked helpful, the community user downvotes the post. Not only that, but it *is* an attempt to answer a question, it is even a correct answer, though incomplete. The flag was wrong, and a VLQ flag would be even more wrong.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've never seen good guidance about VLQ on meta SO. It always seems to repeat the same clear examples and hedges on answers that are well-formed English sentences but with no discernible relationship with the question. There is however a major practical difference, which is that VLQ flags get a chance of being handled without moderator intervention thanks to the low quality review queue. In this case, I don't call “it's a typo” an attempt to answer the question; it just says that the answer exists but doesn't say what the answer is. That's not even a partial answer.

Comment: Unless this changed recently, NAA _also_ goes to the LQP queue first.

Comment: "it just says that the answer exists but doesn't say what the answer is" Yes. It's _not even as good_ as a link-only answer, because it provides no guidance whatsoever towards a solution. In [the world of Shog's answer analogy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/159251), it's a photograph of a drawing of an apple. @TinyGiant.

Comment: Except for upvoted or accepted answers, which also go to a mod queue even if they get 6 recommend deletion votes @Kendra

Comment: @JoshCaswell, it is an incomplete answer, as such it should be downvoted and delete voted, but it is an answer so it should not be flagged. If it were a complete answer it would identify what the typo was and where, but not saying that doesn't make it not an attempt at an answer.

Comment: Everybody always parrots "it is an answer", "it is an attempt at an answer". We [have standards for what "answer" means](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). This is "commentary on the question"; it is "not even a partial answer to the actual question", because the actual question is "what needs to change in this code to make it do <whatever>?" It flat-out does not attempt to provide a solution. How do you use this post to fix the problem in the question?

Comment: I should mention that I don't see the answer in question as an attempt at an answer, but rather as an "oh, so that's what it was, thanks." It just happens to mention the issue that caused the error.

Comment: @Josh Just because an answer could also exist as a comment, does not make the answer any less an answer in and of itself. Just like a comment also being suitable as an answer does not in and of itself make the comment not a comment. It is a horrible incomplete answer yes, but not every horrible incomplete answer qualifies for flags. It should be downvoted and delete voted.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Given that the solution lies only in the answerer's mind, I'd say it's a photograph of the reverse side of a drawing of an apple...

Comment: @Gilles - ...pasted into a Word document, screenshotted, and attached to an email.

Comment: @Josh your edited example above: "How do you use this post to fix the problem in the question?" would then also apply to well written and explained wrong answers, which currently do not qualify for flags.

Comment: No it doesn't, @TinyGiant, because I can at least try them and then find out they're wrong.

Comment: See? Now your definition is getting even more subjective. So now you have to be able to take the answer and apply it to the question for it to be an answer, that means the moderator reviewing it has to be have knowledge in the domain to be able to know if the flag is correct or not. What if something has code, but to those with domain knowledge, the code cannot be applied to the question? Would it then be not an answer?

Comment: “now you have to be able to take the answer and apply it to the question for it to be an answer” Well, yes, obviously. An answer doesn't stand alone, otherwise we'd call it a blog post or something. A code-only answer whose code that isn't just copied from the question (and yes, I've seen my share of these) would be a valid answer (correct or not, that's a different consideration) if the question is asking for code (but not if the question is asking why something is happening).

Comment: @Gilles but the mods don't see the question when reviewing NaA flags, so how can they apply it to the question? Even if they could, they may not have the necessary domain knowledge to do so.

Comment: I didn't say wrong answers should be deleted via NAA, @TinyGiant.

Comment: @TinyGiant The question isn't shown by default (only the title), but it's only one click away. I don't know about SO, but on the sites that I moderate or have moderated, I'd say most VLQ/NAA don't even require looking at the question. For the ones that do, well, I click and look at the question. It's very rare to need domain knowledge to decide on an answer flag (much less common than to decide about closure). If an answer needs to be deleted but it might take extra knowledge or nontrivial observation, which is pretty rare, a custom flag is best (at least on non-SO sites).

Answer (score 4):

1. Even if it was NAA, flagging it is a waste of time, as the question will be deleted as not reproducible, hence deleting any answers.
2. Don't sweat having flags declined. I've had a flag of NAA declined and then the post was deleted, I don't care. People are busy, Mods are especially busy. Just focus on keeping the helpful flag percentage high.