# Trying to understand "Not an answer" flag with off-topic answers

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I just got my First Post flag declined and am trying to improve my understanding of when to flag answers that are not trying to answer the questions. I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46023734/553596) as not an answer, but already was a bit unsure while flagging.

I read a few times through the question and the code and the help text for the "Not an answer" flag and concluded that something that is talking about the same topic, but not at all about the problem of the question, should be flagged.

Is my understanding of "Not an answer" flags wrong and should this post not have been flagged? Is there something else that I should have done during the review?

Comment: That post might be wrong, but it looks like it tries to answer the question (or at least give helpful hints which might lead to an answer), therefore you should vote on it, not flag it.

Comment: @Tom For me during the review it was more a question about a problem with C code in a projectile motion code and the answer then talks about what projectile motion is. But thanks for the suggestion, will downvote such a response the next time.

Comment: The answer was irrelevant, held no useful information for solving the problem, and [should have been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) (and has been, now). But [flag lawyers have firmly established the definition of NAA as "anything that anyone managed to post in the answer space"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314395/is-a-self-answer-of-looks-like-i-had-a-typo-really-not-naa/314435#314435), so raising it has become pointless.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Not "flag lawyers", mods/SE employees did that. There was even a post by a mod on a meta page (I guess it was MSO) stating that an answer post doesn't even need to answer the question where it was posted to, it can also answer any question which might be available in Stack Overflow. Too bad I can't find that post anymore :( (I hope it was deleted for being nonsense).