# Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?

Tags: discussion

I see that this question has been asked many times but it seems that some users do not know how to handle these types of questions. I ask this question to show the following question:

[Print in text file is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875925/print-in-text-file-is-failing)

I have indicated that this type of questions should not be answered but still says that it is correct to answer it, the asker also says that it is a typographical error. What should the community do, close it or ignore it?

Comment: Close as not reproducible.

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Close all the typo questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342)*

Comment: "*this type (?) [...] still says...*" doesn't make sense to me in the sentence: "*I have indicated that this type of questions should not be answered but still says that it is correct to answer it*"... Grammatically, only "*this type (of questions)*" can be the subject of "*says*", but I don't really understand the meaning... (+ The Link is dead btw... (in 2022-05))

Comment: @chivracq 1. I'm not very good at the English language, sorry. 2. The link is not dead but has been hidden, when you have more reputation you will be able to see the deleted questions.

Comment: @OP, yeah well the Wording was apparently good enough "at the time of your Qt" for enough People to understand it, I only realized "a bit later" that the Thread was "a bit older", bumped by 'Com-Bot'... '' Yep I know about the 10k-Rep Req to see 'Deleted Qt's', I hope to manage to check the Content of that Qt in the year 3015...! (+ I only get +100-Rep per year in the Tag I answer..., but no Pb, I can wait...)

Comment: I'm more curious why answers that correct a simple typo often get multiple upvotes. And the typo may have already been pointed out in a comment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The post is unlikely to be helpful for future users, so it doesn't help anyone if we keep it opened. Close it as:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely
>   inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem
>   before posting.

Comment: Not that the text says `this one was resolved`, so this close reason should be used only after the question has been "resolved", either by an answer, or by a comment.

Answer (score 17):

This answer assumes that "typo" refers to "one-off typing mistake that doesn't end up becoming relevant to a wide audience (e.g. because the typo appears to be such a specific gotcha that lots of people unwittingly fall into that same trap)", which, incidentally, is when the so-called "typo" close reason does not apply, because the real purpose of that close reason is not to remove questions about typos, but to remove questions that can and should be forgotten about.

---

Technically, you could point out in an answer that the problem is due to a typo, the asker could acknowledge it as a boo-boo on their part, and *then* the question could be closed as a typo. I have a pet name for this type of closure: a "retroactive closure", because the close reason only becomes apparent after the question has been answered.

But the entire point of closing such questions is that they are no longer relevant after the mistake has been discovered and corrected. It's a one-off mistake that can be swept under the rug and forgotten about. So answering such questions is counter-productive for two reasons:

1. Once the answer receives an upvote, the asker is prevented from deleting their own question after acknowledging that they messed up, thereby subjecting the question to downvotes for all kinds of reasons as long as it remains around.
2. Once the question *is* deleted by vote, Roomba, etc, assuming it doesn't take 60 whole days for that to happen the asker ends up forfeiting any rep they might have gained or lost from answering the question.

Instead, you should generally treat the act of pointing out a typo in a question as a request for clarification, rather than an attempt at answering. A typo can either be

1. a mistake made during the time of posting that changes the meaning of the question, and is *not* consequential to the problem that prompted the question to begin with, or
2. the actual problem that prompted the question to begin with.

Even if, like me sometimes, you're *sure* that the typo was #2, this is one of those times where I'd say it's perfectly acceptable to violate the "don't post answers as comments" rule and just leave a comment. That way you make it easier to close and remove the question so everyone can forget about it and move on to the next, actually pressing, problem.

If someone *has* posted an answer, don't sweat it. Certainly [don't fixate so much on the answer that you forget about the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314395/is-a-self-answer-of-looks-like-i-had-a-typo-really-not-naa/314398#314398). Just let the answerer know that the question is going to be closed (or is closed) and there's a good chance their answer is going to go away if the question is eventually removed.

Answer (score 1):

I would "follow up" on BoltClock's answer with a slightly different differentiation between two types of "typo" (or, at least, two different types of close-voting as typos).

Sticking to my 'native' C++ language, an example of the first would be something like a question that asks, "Why does my `for` loop never end?" with code shown that includes the following line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 42; j++) {
```

Here, it is almost certain that the `j++` is a typographical error, where `i++` was intended. So, in this case, closing as a typo (and leaving a comment with the correction) is entirely appropriate – and, IMHO, posting an answer is decidedly *inappropriate* (although there are some rep-hungry folks that will, nonetheless, post an answer and get their +15/+25 for it).

The second type is slightly more 'controversial'. An example would be the use of the `=` (assignment) operator instead of the `==` (comparison) operator. Now, although such usage – in a line of code like `if (a = 42) {` – ***may*** be due to a typographical error, it is equally (if not more) likely that it is a misunderstanding of the language by a beginner.

In my experience, questions like this are frequently closed as typos (presumably, because they can be answered in comments and, thus, "resolved in a way unlikely to be helpful to future readers"). However, in such cases, there will **almost certainly be a duplicate question** addressing the issue. Now, although looking for (and finding) such a duplicate may involve more work from the curator, closing as a duplicate is far more appropriate and far more helpful. If a good, duplicate target (suitable for use as the "canonical") cannot be found, and the question is otherwise well-presented, then consider posting a good answer (including a thorough explanation and links to relevant language Standards and/or references), so that it can be used as that canonical in future. (For the `=` *versus* `==` issue, I did manage to find [this canonical Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399792/10871073) – but it took a bit of searching!)

'Basic level' questions that fall into the second category **are not unwelcome** on Stack Overflow; indeed, many of the canonicals for these have become extremely popular Q/As, with huge view counts and upvotes. Furthermore, for those curators with the gold tag-badge hammer, it is (much) quicker to close vote as a duplicate than it is to cast 1 of the 3 required CVs to close as a "typo".

Comment: Anything we can do as a community to make it easier to find that kind of canonical? Just using the site search is an incredible pain, especially since the typo generally revolves around symbols like `=`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree that finding the canonical dupe is often difficult. Some things can be done: once found, add it to your bookmarks; ask in a chatroom, like SOCVR or a language-specific room. Or, use Google instead of the native SO search engine. :)

Comment: You might consider having a canonical like these describing what symbols mean what, only for C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: @CertainPerformance Maybe. My concern with using such as targets is that they can become "RTFM" magnets.

Comment: I don't quite understand the concern. If people vote to close a "what does X symbol mean?" question as a duplicate of "what do all these symbols mean?", why is that bad? Or are you suggesting that the existence of the dupe target somehow encourages rude or abusive comments? I doubt it. I think rude or abusive comments come primarily from people who *intuit* that "TFM" includes the necessary information. If they're angry enough to comment like that, why would they double-check? And if they did double check, why would they not just put in the close vote?