# What are the steps to be taken if I think a question has been closed for wrong reasons?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags, closed-questions

Yesterday, I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67742256/whats-wrong-c) (that now happens to be deleted). The question did not show much research effort, and the OP definitely did not put any effort into debugging. However, the question was closed with the "Not reproducible or a Typo" reason.

The thing is, the typo was a genuine mistake on the OP's part, and the code in the question, when copy-pasted, did give an error (it was supposed to, the semi-colon was missing).

However, the missing semi-colon, as per one of the OP's comments, happened to be a genuine mistake, and `please add a semi-colon` could have been a proper acceptable answer.

As I think the question was closed for the wrong reasons, I notified the mods who declined the flag:

[image: the mod reply]

I would like to know what steps are expected in such situations.

Comment: the question was closed with the reason "Not reproducible or Typo" and you say that the problem was indeed caused by a genuine typo, so it sounds like the correct close reason was used? "please add a semi-colon" also does not sound like an answer that would be helpful or interesting to anyone besides the op.

Comment: Please note that it also doesn't go well with the community when you jump to conclusions that your opinion is the only correct one out there (not to mention referring to moderator actions as "shooting you down").

Comment: @OlegValter *when you jump to conclusions that your opinion is the only correct one out there*: I am really sorry if you felt so. I didn't mean (nor was thinking) anything like that, because in that case, my question would have been hinting towards a mistake on the mod's part and not be asking what is expected of someone :)

Comment: @kesarling - no worries, just an editor's note - intention and tone are hard to decipher online, plus we get a lot of complaints that the closure was incorrect or the appointed mods were on the wrong, while the claims are usually unsubstantiated.

Comment: Can you explain which future visitors would gain benefit from an answer of "please add a semi-colon"? What problem do they need to have and how would they search for it to find that question *and* be helped by the answer?

Comment: @VLAZ, I forgot to mention this, but the problem was not only a missing semicolon, but also illegal C++ code. `int nummberOfElements; int arr[numberOfElements];` is not valid C++ code

Comment: @kesarling right, so would you say it's *likely* this solution will help future readers?

Comment: @VLAZ No, that is why I wrote that "answer" as a comment. I am not talking about the solution, but rather about the flag on the question. Even if the semi-colon were to be a typo, the question should either have been marked as duplicate (for I am sure this is not the first time someone has tried to declare a C++ array like that) or needs debugging details.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ it was a typo and the solution doesn't seem to benefit future readers. The close reason seems fine. If you have a duplicate because it's a very common mistake feel free to post it. Overall changing the close reasons is rarely worth it. And one is as good as another if they overlap.

Comment: From [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/12892553) *This answer assumes that "typo" refers to "one-off typing mistake that doesn't end up becoming relevant to a wide audience (e.g. because the typo appears to be such a specific gotcha that lots of people unwittingly fall into that same trap)", which, incidentally, is when the so-called "typo" close reason does not apply, because the real purpose of that close reason is not to remove questions about typos, but to remove questions that can and should be forgotten about*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with the OP's code is that it had a missing `;`. This should definitely be closed as a "Typo", since the compiler catches this.  Misunderstandings that lead to errors are fine, but errors that are caught by a compiler are generally not useful to anyone else. Answers such as "*please add a semi-colon*" are in fact a prime example of where the Typo reason is applicable, and so the closure was correct.

In this case, the question could also have been validly closed as "Needing debugging details", since the OP said the code was not working, but failed to mention any details about it. Closing as "Needs details or clarity" would also have been fine. In any case, even if the question had been closed for the *wrong* reasons, it's not worth the effort required, i.e. 3 reopen votes, and an additional 3 close votes (1 in case it should be closed as a duplicate), just to change the close banner message.

If you feel a question was closed incorrectly, i.e. it shouldn't have been closed at all, you can vote to reopen the post. If the post was closed correctly, but an edit has made it reopenable, you can still vote to reopen. This puts the question into the reopen queue, where it will be reviewed by other members of the community. In case no edit was required to make the question worth reopening, and you don't have the ability to cast reopen votes, you can make a `reopen-pls` request in the [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) chatroom. You definitely shouldn't flag for moderator attention in these cases, because it's not really their job to curate content; that's something the community does as far as possible, and moderators should only be notified when it's an issue only they can handle.