# Close-voting and answering questions (and the dupehammer version of it)

Tags: discussion, support, dupehammer, behavior

I am questioning some users' behavior and the way SO works.

Let's take the following examples:

- A user votes to close a question (for whatever reason) **then** posts an answer to that question
- A user answers a question **then** votes to close it (within a short time frame, let's say 24 hours)
- A user with a Gold Badge, answers a question, **then** uses their dupehammer and closes it as a duplicate (again, within a short time frame)

I believe this kind of behavior is questionable and has a smell of *I know this question should be closed, but let's place an answer anyway so I can get some more reputation points...*

Of course, you could *accidentally* cast a close vote, forget to retract it and place an answer, but **what if this is a repeated behavior?**

What I also question (in the way SO works) is that if an answer was provided and the question was closed, the OP can still accept the answer and upvote it (and so can other users too).

I have read [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286283/should-users-be-permitted-to-both-answer-and-close-a-question) but IMO the accepted answer doesn't fully address the question.

- When I see such repeated behavior, should I do anything?
- Why does SO allow askers of closed questions to accept (one of) the provided answer?

Comment: It's not allowed. It can happen sometime and it's not a huge deal, but if a user has a habit of doing it then please flag for mod attention.

Comment: @Dharman do you mean that the 3 example behaviors I gave in my question are not allowed? If yes, then why does the system allow it?

Comment: No, I meant that repeated behaviour like this is not allowed.

Comment: All right. Which is also why I believe some mechanisms could prevent that (in particular, my 3rd example, and the fact that the asker of a closed question still can accept an answer...).

Comment: I don't think there needs to be a system-level solution. Having a clear pattern of this behaviour is an exception. We have exception handlers. At most, maybe the system can raise a modflag when enough of these actions happen. But maybe it's enough to have a SEDE query that identifies such users.

Comment: @VLAZ I get your point. It's too *anecdotic* for the system to prevent that. But in a way, if there is no modflag, how would mods know the frequency of such actions? Does a SEDE query already exist for that?

Comment: I'm not very well versed in the existing SEDE queries. I'm going to guess "no", though.

Comment: And I am not well versed into writing them. I'll give it a try though but if anyone wants to give it a shot... please feel free!

Comment: I guess the question is... should you feel pressured to delete an answer you've already provided if you can, because you've realized the question should be closed? I don't think the system really does anything to push users in this direction if their answer isn't downvoted.

Comment: @KevinB *because you've realized the question should be closed* - if that's the case, you *might want* to delete your answer. But maybe you should just think twice before answering. I feel though that in some cases it's done on purpose, because it's a repeated chain of events from the same users. That's what I tried to describe in my question.

Comment: @JimG.I don’t think that applies here. Your proposed dupe is about what the answerer should do; this question is about what a third party should do.

Comment: FWIW, I think there is an existing Q&A on why we allow voting (and by extension accepting) on closed Q&A. I cannot find it at the moment, but the TLDR is that this is still published content so it needs the usual content rating mechanism to say what is good and bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286283/109941

Comment: If _"getting more reputation points"_ is the only reason for someone to be on StackOverflow, then it's sad. Reputation points is just a way (not necessarily a good one) to give a "confidence" level on the quality/validity of a post. It's not a goal. If people only ask or answer questions for that only reason, I don't know why they bother being here at first. Personnaly I've never seen someone voting to close AND post an answer, it's contradictory (I don't say it never happened, just it doesn't make sense imho).

Comment: @Fareanor I totally agree with you but trust me, it happens. And from users with like 100K+ reputation. It feels like reputation makes their salary at the end of the month...

Comment: @JimG. I have linked to that last link of yours *in my question* mentioning why I think it doesn't address my question.

Comment: @JimG. btw why are you trying to get my question closed when you have answered it yourself?

Comment: This is a really big problem on this network. You wouldn't have to look hard to find users that participate in this kind of malicious behavior. It's part of the elite levels of the game.

Comment: @MrUpsidown *why are you trying to get my question closed when you have answered it yourself?* non-literary irony?

Comment: But seriously, I have had a change of heart from time to time. I first retract the close vote, though.

Comment: _I know this question should be closed, but let's place an answer anyway so I can get some more reputation points_: At the end of the day what are reputation points worth? Absolutely nothing.  It's my understanding that SO is owned by MS. One would think that perhaps reputation points could be used towards MS product subscriptions such as a Visual Studio subscription.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that this doesn't seem to be about the regex tag.

Comment: I've closed my questions, after I usually answered them myself. Is this bad?

Comment: @Binit could be. You're preventing someone else who comes along later from showing you how to do whatever the question is about even better than what you came up with if you close the question. That said, I'm seeing self-accepted answers, not closed questions, in your account. Doesn't mean you didn't close AND delete them, but you should reserve deletion for unfixable questions. Seen too many people shocked by bans from deleted question icebergs. And I honestly don't know if you can close your own questions. Never tried.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Flag it for mod attention.

This is an awkward variant of the [Slowest Cheater in the East](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/175248) in which someone who does this could be cast as looking to boost their answer only, or allow their answer to receive upvotes.  Or worse, it represents a paradox - the question is both on-topic enough to be answered, but off-topic enough to be closed, which cannot be the perspective of the answerer at the same time.

Comment: I described another possibility in my answer: I might think a question is badly posed or a duplicate but want to help the questioner anyway.  I close questions to improve the site.  I answer questions to help people who read my answer.  Sometimes I can do both things at once.

Comment: Ditto. Just came across an example: the user says he's looked at the existing Qs on the topic and tried the answers and they don't work. In that situation closing as a duplicate seems very unhelpful. But yet, the question is a duplicate. We don't know why the answers don't work, but perhaps if we phrase the answer slightly differently...

Comment: @user2554330: If you want to help just the one user, and/or explain why it's a duplicate, use comments.

Comment: Wouldn't an automated task running a SEDE-query that queries the amount and frequency of a user casting a close vote before or after having answered a question (exceeding a certain threshold in total amount and frequency could lead to a warning or other authorative measures) be way more effective and reduce the burden on the mods? (tbh, I am guilty of having done this, but literally only a couple of times since I joined SE). Without mentioning names, on TWP there are a couple of users who do this quite often on a regular basis, almost like a habit..

Comment: Today I flagged an answer from a user who frequently does what I described. We'll see what's the outcome of my flag.

Comment: My flag was marked as *helpful* with the comment *Thanks — contacted the user* - no further info.

Answer (score 4):

> A user votes to close a question (for whatever reason) then posts an answer to that question

This is never ok. If a question is on-topic, not a duplicate and can be answered, then it shouldn't be closed. Or vice versa, don't answer it if it should be closed.

> A user answers a question then votes to close it (within a short time frame, let's say 24 hours)
>
> A user with a Gold Badge, answers a question then uses their dupehammer and closes it as a duplicate (again, within a short time frame)

This isn't necessarily abuse, you'll have to consider these on case-by-case basis. Because the following scenario is fairly common and OK:

- Someone writes an answer to a question.
- After answering they realize that they have misunderstood the question because it is unclear or that a duplicate exists. Or possibly the OP has changed the question so that nothing makes sense.
- The person who wrote the answer then participates in the close voting.

Comment: Let's say that *you* are the answerer in the last scenario you have described above. What would you do with your answer?

Comment: And how about when a Gold Badge user answers a question and uses their dupehammer 1 minute after posting the question to close it as a duplicate (and leave their answer)?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: "*And how about when a Gold Badge user answers a question and uses their dupehammer 1 minute after posting the question to close it as a duplicate (and leave their answer)?*" And what about if a 3rd person posts a comment providing a duplicate, which will naturally be deleted after the post gets dupe-hammered?

Comment: @NicolBolas that *could* happen although I doubt that in the many cases I have seen this behavior it's happened every time. In this event, is the *comment action* from that 3rd person also taken off the timeline?

Comment: For the second situation, I don't see any reason not to delete the answer after dupe hammering. There is no point in keeping an answer to the wrong question (due to misunderstanding the one that was actually asked).

Comment: @MrUpsidown Like I said, case by case basis. If the answer no longer makes sense, then delete it. If the answer answers the question, but the question is a duplicate (and the dupe target is better), then such question/answers are often left as "goal posts" for search engines. Although if there are no upvotes nor accepted answers I think Roomba will delete closed-as-duplicate eventually. Ideally one should strive not to cast any close votes in situations where one could be considered partial - at least I try to follow that even if there's no requirement to do so by the site rules.

Comment: All of this assumes a binary model: a Q is either a duplicate or it isn't. That's not the case in real life. There might be a comprehensive answer but it's clear the OP won't understand it because they haven't grasped the concepts. Or the question might be different but the answer is the same. Or the question is the same but the answer isn't very clear (or is wrong or incomplete). So you answer the question, then you think, hang on, it would be better to improve the existing answer and close the Q as a dup; or even vice-versa, you close it as a dup and then realise that won't help the user.

Comment: @Lundin I believe this is an appropriate behavior. What I tried to describe in my question is repeated behavior, by *some users*, that simply don't seem to be playing the same rules... their goal seems to be to place an answer, whatever the question quality, and VTC at the same time. And they will *never* delete their answer after casting a close vote.

Comment: @MichaelKay How is "you'll have to consider these on case-by-case basis" a binary model? Did you read the answer? Because your comment seems to just repeat the same arguments I made there.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Hence case by case. If someone has a clear, repeatedly occurring pattern of answering + close voting, then they should be reported to the moderators.

Comment: @Lundin I was commenting on the statement "If a question is on-topic, not a duplicate and can be answered, then it shouldn't be closed". I think it's rarely clear-cut deciding whether a question is a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a problem with user behaviour, it's a problem with SO awarding points when it shouldn't.  If a question is closed, then the user who posted an answer shouldn't get any points for it.  If they already got points, those should be taken away.  Almost nobody can see the answer, so what benefit is it to the community?

On the other hand, the person who posted the question can see the answer.  It might benefit them.  If I choose to be altruistic and post an answer that just benefits one person, that shouldn't be seen as abusing the system.  The only reason it could be abuse is because of the broken system that awards me points.

Maybe this will discourage people from answering questionable questions, because they might lose their reward.  That would be a good thing.  There are poor questions on SO that are open only because someone has already answered them.

EDITED to add:  I don't know if I've done this enough to meet the standard of "repeated behaviour" mentioned in the question, but I think I've voted to close a question and also answered it more than once.  I always assumed that I wouldn't get points for those answers.  Now I know I might have got some, but I'm going to continue to do it when it makes sense, even if @MrUpsidown thinks it smells bad.

Comment: This seems problematic to enforce reliably.

Comment: @Makoto:  It could be completely automatic.  If a question is closed, no more points are awarded, and points already awarded go away.  What's problematic?

Comment: If I answer a question that is then closed, I lose my points in this scheme, even if the closure was unjustified (e.g. some group of people decide to target vote my content, but have a more outsized impact if they close the questions that I answered).  This isn't an "algorithm fix the thing"-problem, this is a "social behavior"-problem.

Comment: That's true, but the problem is improperly closing questions to attack someone else.  A group of people could also just target all of my posts for downvoting and they'd probably have a bigger effect on my point total.  Both of those are behaviours that should be sanctioned.  Helping an individual and at the same time acting to clean up the site is not.

Comment: Yes, both behaviors are already sanctioned.  But why allow such damage to occur in the first place?  Tying reputation gain or rep earned to whether or not a question is closed is such a risky thing that I don't trust the team to be able to implement an algorithm on this that doesn't carry some outsized risk.

Comment: There are two kinds of damage here.  The important kind of damage would be damage to the site when a good question with good answers is improperly closed.  Less important would be damage to my point count.  But if a question is good and the answers are good enough so that a substantial point count is involved, surely it will be pretty obvious to everyone that the closing was inappropriate.

Comment: Disagree on loosing points for closure, at least if it is no more diversified. Curation regularly leads to closure of longstanding, roughly equal questions as duplicates - the really isn’t a clearly wrong question before the closure, and it would be arbitrary to remove points from one.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi:  That's a good point.  Maybe the proposal should be time limited:  points are removed from answers to questions that are closed within a day (or a week, or whatever) after they are asked.

Comment: *This isn't a problem with user behaviour* - well until such a *solution* would be in place, I believe it is. I do question the way this works with reputation though (and I mentioned that in my question). What I don't get from your points is *when* do you think it *makes sense* to VTC and answer. If a question meets the standards, isn't a duplicate and deserves an answer, why would you VTC? And if the Q is bad, just VTC and skip. No?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: No.  Sometimes the user asks a bad question but would benefit from an answer even if nobody else would.  Then I might give them one, as a comment or a full answer if the comment format doesn't work.

Comment: So what is the problem of giving answers to bad questions?  The only problem is that some people think you are unfairly getting points.  I really don't care about the points, and you shouldn't either.

Comment: Re *"it's a problem with SO awarding points when it shouldn't"*: Yes, the incentives are for a ticket system (helpdesk, (paid) homework, and work orders), not a non-redundant (other than required for search engine efficiency) repository of knowledge.

Comment: *So what is the problem of giving answers to bad questions?* - if the question ends up staying open, I believe it's a problem. Doing so just crams the site (and the search engines) with poorly worded, vague and unhelpful content. When I use SO hoping to find an answer to a technical issue, I expect to find quality content.

Comment: Answers also prevent or at least complicate automated cleanup. There is a lot of junk sticking around just because it has an answer that got an arbitrary upvote.

Comment: @MrUpsidown:  if the question ends up staying open, then there weren't two more votes to close it after mine, even though my vote would have put it in the close votes queue.  So reviewers have decided that it deserved to stay open.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, if posting an answer makes automatic cleanup harder, then that's a problem with the rules for automatic cleanup.  If the question has been voted closed, then it should be invisible to most visitors, and should eventually be deleted once it's clear it won't be reopened.  If the rules don't act that way, then the rules should be fixed.

Comment: @user2554330 Well, I encourage everyone who wants to close and answer to propose such a rule change. Until then, that is how cleanup works and how close-and-answer negativity affects the side.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I think you have it backwards.  People who don't want me to be able to answer and vote to close should propose a rule change to prevent it, or a rule change that makes life easier for those who claim to be adversely affected by it.

Answer (score 2):

> A user answers a question then votes to close it (within a short time frame, let's say 24 hours)

I've never done this, but from my understanding of the not-reproducible/typo close reason, isn't this exactly one of the proper ways to use it?

That close reason's description says (emphasis added):

> While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one **was resolved** in a way less likely to help future readers.

So by my understanding of that description, if you use that close reason, the question needs to be already resolved- either in the comments, or by posting an answer.

Ideally the asker would verify the correctness of the resolution by a comment-reply or accepting the answer, but I wouldn't blame a sufficiently knowledgeable resolver for not waiting for that to happen before voting to close with this close reason.

Is my understanding correct here?

Update thanks to [@MrUpsidown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1238965/mrupsidown): Answering typo questions and then close-voting is not forbidden, but there are good reasons to just comment instead of posting an answer: See [this MSO Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/11107541) and [this MSE Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174389/997587).

Comment: My understanding is that the question is either *not reproducible* **or** *caused by a typo*. If it's not reproducible, it doesn't deserve an answer (how would you answer if you can't reproduce?) and if the issue was caused by a typo, you might simply tell the OP in a comment that they have a typo here or there and VTC. I don't think it deserves an answer in any of the 2 cases.

Comment: sure, but isn't that a personal thing? Is there an established community guideline that says not to write answer posts for typo questions? I haven't seen one (granted, I haven't looked for one).

Comment: Some hints [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question).

Comment: @MrUpsidown edited to inline. thanks so much! today I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

Close-voting a question, or dupehammering it, means *"nobody should be allowed to answer this question"*.  For whatever reason.

If you close-vote a question and also answer it, in either order, you're saying *"I'm the only person in the world who should be allowed to answer this question"*.  That seems intolerably arrogant to me.

Nobody should be doing this.  The issue though is whether it should be somehow punished.  Is it really worth taking up a moderator's time, to deal with this particular situation?  I think not.  My suggestion would be that you put a comment calling out the behaviour, and leave it at that.  I've done that in the past.

Comment: I'm the only person in the world who should be allowed to answer this question... False. The community might disagree. And if they do, you might as well help the OP with your answer.

Comment: @JimG. No, close voting means you believe it should be closed, and therefore unanswerable by others.  Whether the community agrees or not.

Comment: Yes. It means *you* believe. The community may not believe. And if they don't... Go ahead and answer the question. Provide value.

Comment: So I should do things that I believe nobody should do?  OK, Jim.

Comment: I think down-voting answers by such users might be an efficient way to self-police the behavior. They are likely users of the "rep farming" variety.

Comment: I don't agree with this: "if you close-vote a question and also answer it, in either order, you're saying "I'm the only person in the world who should be allowed to answer this question"". These situations might be a fair bit more nuanced than that. Often you might not realize that a question is unclear or a duplicate before you've started to write an answer, or after you post an answer and the OP leaves some comment "doesnt work because..." and _then_ you realize what their actual problem is. ->

Comment: At that point you've still taken the time to write an answer and the question turning out to be bad is not a fault of the answerer, if the question seemed OK and answerable at the time when they wrote the answer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The close voter does not have unilateral ability to close the question. The close voter is merely part of a broader community. The community decides if the question should be closed.

Comment: @Lundin Yes! That too. You might answer the question and discover a duplicate **candidate** later. Again... We are only talking about duplicate candidates.

Comment: @Lundin If you realise after answering a question that it shouldn't have been answered, for whatever reason, you have the option of deleting your answer.  And if the reason the question shouldn't have been answered was because it was a duplicate, you can always move your answer to the duplicate question, so that your effort was not wasted.

Comment: @JimG. That's like saying "I voted for Trump, even though I wanted Biden to be president, because it's not just my vote that decides the presidency".

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Terrible analogy. But what I will say is that if my candidate doesn't win the presidency, then I still need to live my life as a citizen.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem [Here is a really offensive example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74320310/2985643) from a high rep user. Note only did they close vote the question and answer it, but they even edited the question first, and did all of that within 30 minutes of the question being posted! The OP even accepted their answer. I think if you vote to close a question you should not be permitted to also post an answer, and vice versa. As you suggest, I did _"put a comment calling out the behaviour"_, but received no response.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are cases where I have answered a question, then someone has commented on my answer pointing to a duplicate, and in consequence I have concurred with a close-vote. I don't see any reason to delete my answer in that situation.

Comment: @MichaelKay That's an excellent point.  I would argue that in that situation, it's possibly worth copy-pasting your answer across to the duplicate, where more people will see it.  I know that your answers are invariably of very high quality, and very much worth sharing.  Unless of course, the duplicate question already has an answer very similar to yours.

Answer (score -3):

I've voted to close my own question, after I answered it. The answer I gave was the reason why the question should be closed.
I didn't delete the question immediately because people had already seen it, and I HATE that behaviour, just 'disappearing' something because you've found out more information (even if 'more information' is just a better question). Let it close: I thought the question was good enough to ask, others will think the same, and can see my close reason. If, eventually, closed questions are deleted, that's fine: I'd like to leave it visible for a little while.

Answer (score -11):

To me, this seems like a prime example of Meta being completely out of touch with reality, and being more concerned with their own little world, and enforcing their own rules than they are about actually helping users. It's a large part of why SO has a worldwide reputation as a toxic place that's actively hostile to new users.

Following the behavior this question takes for granted is "right" is a large part of what's slowly killing the site, and giving it this reputation for hostility.

If you look around places like Reddit and Quora (among many others) you quickly find that a lot of new users hate when their question gets closed without being answered directly. I don't mean just dislike a little bit. I mean hate with the fiery passion of ten thousand suns. Even when it's clear it really is the hundredth duplicate of a common question, they still hate its being closed without being answered directly--especially when (as is often the case) it's a simple question with a simple answer.

To give new users a reasonably "gentle" introduction to the site, if they ask a question that's reasonably topical and has a relatively easy, simple answer, it's better to write them an answer, so they don't feel like they're being rejected.

Yes, if it's a dupe, it should also be closed as a dupe. If it's asked poorly, it should be edited or possibly closed entirely.

With a little care, we can keep the site neat, orderly and organized *without* making new users feel like they've been rejected as unworthy of our attention and help. And a large part of that is simply giving them an answer when possible, even when (for the sake of the site as a whole) we also need to close their question.

## Summary

New users deserve help rather than being treated in a way they perceive as hostile and demeaning (regardless of how well intended). Keep the site neat as well, but without being hostile to new users.

## Personal

If you think I've profited from both answering and closing questions, feel free to take away whatever amount of reputation you feel is appropriate. That's not why I do it, but if it makes you feel better, it doesn't bother me either.

Comment: This represents the problem.  There are always going to be parties that disagree with both convention and site policy and insist on answering anyway, which leads to this mixed experience for users on the site.  We're not any of those other sites, and we shouldn't look to ape their user experience.  We've defined our own workflow, and that means - if a question is a dupe, then closing it as a dupe is strongly preferred over answering it.

Comment: I'm not talking about imitating any other site. I'm talking about reading what people have to say about [SO]. And the answer to that is simple: people hate SO by a margin of about 90:1 (and most who've helped a lot of people on SO have just about the same attitude toward Meta). Bottom line: in this case, Meta's position on what should happen is wrong.

Comment: Yes, people dislike having their question closed as a dupe, but the message of closing it as a dupe and saying "hey, your answer is actually over there!!" isn't one of those things that we mere mortals can solve.  [I touched on this years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386324/1079354) but the site isn't moved to "fix" this UX piece yet.  This is also why I really don't care if they call me, the site or others who follow this convention "toxic".

Comment: It's also not the case that I *disagree* that there could be an improvement here.  It's just that going against convention and policy is expressly *not* the way to achieve it.

Comment: @Makoto: If SO were to do some work on the UI, perhaps they could achieve something better. But for now, by far the best choice that's actually available is to both answer and close most of the time.

Comment: **We have already established that answering and closing as a duplicate is not the best practice for the site.**  While I have to accept that you are going to not follow site norms or policies, I refuse to accept that as "the best option" in any scenario.

Comment: @Makoto: You may have *accepted* it as "best practice" among yourselves. You haven't *established* anything beyond the fact that you care more about your own opinion than you do about the users of the site.

Comment: Re *"actually helping users"*: The ***vast*** majority of users are not asking questions on Stack Overflow. They struggle with low-scored duplicates (from search engine results) with incomplete and low-quality answers. And with no indication of where the canonical question is.

Comment: Isn't this the entire point of the close/re-open features? Unlike on Quora or Reddit, closed questions can be re-opened. If Joe's question gets closed as a duplicate, a banner appears at the top with a link to the duplicate. Joe can then go to the question and read through the answers. If he finds one that solves his problem, then great, the site has served it's purpose. If not, he can edit his question to explain why it is different than the suggested duplicate then check the little box at the bottom and it could get re-opened and answered. I don't see a problem with just closing it outright.

Comment: @Jesse: Please read what was actually said. I'm not talking about how Quora or Reddit (etc.) work. I'm talking about what people in the outside world think of [SO]. By a *wide* margin, the outside world thinks that SO sucks horribly. People who really need what SO could provide stay away in droves, almost entirely because of things that people here on Meta are absolutely convinced are the right thing to do.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Please read what was actually said. And I *certainly* haven't said that duplicates should be left open.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I did read what was said. Did you read what I said? A huge part of your point was that users hate getting their questions closed without a direct answer. Sure a duplicate isn't *technically* a direct answer, but it's one click away. And, if it doesn't answer the question, then after a bit of clarification it can be re-opened and answered. I don't see a problem here. The user gets their question answered either way, assuming they're willing to put in the effort to ask it.

Comment: @Jesse: Now go out into the rest of the world and read what people have to say about this. *You* don't see a problem. They do. Many see it as a huge problem. Now, I'm perfectly willing to admit that to an extent many of them are being much more emotional than rational. But guess what: that's human nature, and we ignore it at our extreme peril.

Comment: Not to mention, on the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page (a link to which is displayed in a banner at the top of the screen when writing a question), it explicitly says *"Please look around to see if your question has been asked before"*. If new users don't do their due diligence to try and learn how to site is supposed to work and put effort into asking a good question, then realistically, why should regular users of the site put in any more effort than just closing it with the appropriate reason?

Comment: @Jesse: Nobody's saying user *should* necessarily help out. If somebody wants to just vote to close, more power to them. But the question here (and many of the comments even more so) isn't just saying that users should be *allowed* to close without any further effort, but that anybody who does try to help instead should be condemned and punished.

Comment: Answering anyway is all fine and dandy *if you actually clean up afterwards*. I don’t see that happening on any comparable scale than littering takes place. Your closing statement to „feel free to take away whatever amount of reputation you feel is appropriate“ hits the same sentiment - let others worry about the clean up. If you would at least use the same language for both aspects - no, „anybody who does try to help [gets] condemned and punished“ by people „completely out of touch with reality“. Yes, keep playing the victim card and go ahead and blame it on Meta being evil…

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: The subject at hand is solely people who both answer and vote to close. If you want a separate discussion about people who answer things you think they shouldn't, feel free to hold that--but at the very least you need to recognize that it is a completely separate question and discussion. As far as "victim card" goes...please come back after you quit hallucinating.

Comment: *the outside world thinks that SO sucks horribly* - why? Because they asked a question but failed to read a few help pages and to stick with a couple of rules that were made so that SO isn't *just* a huge pile of poorly worded, unreproducible and vague questions, each with dozens of unhelpful answers and got their question closed and/or received a harsh comment? I have rarely seen a new user asking a good question be received hostilely.

Comment: @MrUpsidown: I see it constantly. Multiple times a week, questions get closed because (for one example) somebody has the temerity to say "I need to know how to do X" rather than phrasing as a question: "how do I do X?" Many more provide descriptions that are adequate for people who know the subject matter, but half a dozen people immediately insist on an MVCE. The reality is that the rules are unnecessarily restrictive for many cases, and many are closed for failing to meet expectations that go far beyond what's written down anyway.

Comment: This is one of the core design flaws of the site - public shaming is used as moderation tool. Nobody likes criticism no matter if constructive or not. Nobody likes to be shamed in public. Basic people management skills is to praise people loudly in public, but criticise them discreetly and private. This wasn't taken in account when SO was designed, so there will always be drama - status: by design. But that bad site design doesn't mean that we are obliged to answer the same bad or hopelessly basic questions over and over again.

Comment: People that hate SO and feel rejected are only the ones that doesn't take the time to read the rules. I know they are a majority, it's sad but it's a fact, most of new users doesn't care about anything, step on the rules, do not make any effort/attempt to try to understand and fix their issue. They see SO as a bunch of slaves to do their work for them. I see so many times the same and repeated basic questions that a single google search would have answered more than once. So many time people asking for us to do their homework for them. They feel rejected ? They reap what they sow.

Comment: For me, it's not to SO to rub them up the right way. I am a new user compared to SO lifetime, and I've never felt rejected even I already knew the hostile SO reputation. I just read the rules, followed them. Did some research first before asking a question, do the debugging myself before coming here, etc... I've never had my questions closed for duplicates (I don't even remember if I already had a closed question at all). It's not the problem of SO, it's the problem of disrespectful new users.

Comment: @JerryCoffin “The subject at hand is solely people who both answer and vote to close.” Indeed, and that means [their answers complicate and often outright prevent automated cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Meaning they need someone to clean up after them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Um...your logic seems lacking here. The connection from A to B simply doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @Lundin: And nobody's suggesting that anybody's *obliged* to do anything of the sort. The question (and many comments), however, suggest that there's something evil about writing an answer, and that doing so should be prevented. My position is that writing an answer along with voting to close is fine, and should not be discouraged.

Comment: Obviously writing answers to bad and poorly researched questions will encourage more of the same. You can't just look at this from the individual asker's perspective, you have to consider what's best for the site as whole and what's best for future readers. If a future reader is searching for something and lands in a flood of crap, then SO is harmful, not helpful.

Comment: @Lundin: You might have a point there--if it weren't already a flood of crap. For  years we've been trying to get better questions by essentially telling everybody who's not already an experienced user to go away. That's failed. I think it's time to try something else, such as getting new users to stick around long enough to become experienced users instead.

Comment: @JerryCoffin „Um...your logic seems lacking here. The connection from A to B simply doesn't seem to exist.“ Feel free to tell me what step you think is missing. As far as I can tell, A is “some people close and answer“ and B is „questions that are closed and answered may not get cleaned up automatically”. Those two seem very much connected.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: You seem to be taking for granted that it's always good for them to be deleted ("cleaned up"). Most of them are dupes, and it's much better that they remain, to help others find the canonical answer of which they were a dupe.

Comment: @JerryCoffin SO was not originally meant to be a site for beginners, but a site for programmers, meaning people with at least basic knowledge of at least one programming language. But I think those kind of users came here because of the lack of alternatives. While at the same time, the veterans who signed up here way back never did so while agreeing to be daycare teachers. It has been proposed many times to divide SO into a beginner part and an expert part. Doing so would surely lead to a whole lot less drama and friction.

Comment: @Lundin: I doubt it. Back in the Usenet days we tried that. The area that was supposed to be reserved for the more advanced people was *flooded* with rank beginners. But I also think it's nearly futile to try to divide people into "beginners" and "programmers". Yes, there are a few clear-cut cases--but a whole lot of people fall into a massive grey area.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Well... you seem to be taking for granted that it's always good for them *not* to be deleted, then? There are also roomba rules to prevent useful duplicates from being deleted. Upvotes or even just views will preserve proven signposts. We do not need answers to force questions to remain.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Which could have easily been solved by letting users swiftly and instantly migrate posts to the beginner site.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: No, I'm not taking anything of the sort for granted, nor is such a conclusion necessary to support my position. They don't have to be useful; they merely have to be relatively harmless (and absent evidence to the contrary, which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist) I think most of them are. In the end, I think it mostly comes down to one question: "is the judgement of an experienced user likely to be better than that of a simple "Roomba" more often than not?" And I'm pretty sure the answer is not just "yes', but "hell yes."

Answer (score -26):

I don't see a problem.

---

Imagine a user, let's call him 'Joe'. Joe sees a question and thinks:

- I believe this question is a duplicate, so I'm going to submit a duplicate **candidate** and VTC as "duplicate".
- But... The rest of the Stack Overflow community may not agree that it's a duplicate. And I know the answer to this question. So I will submit a correct answer too.

---

- What was wrong with Joe's behavior?

Comment: Nothing's wrong. But that's not what I described in my question.

Comment: Is Joe going to delete their answer when the question get's closed? If not, I'd consider close voting on a question where I have an answer as a unfair advantage.

Comment: Why does Joe do this repeatedly doing that? And why does Joe care what the rest of the community thinks, given that according to the very premise you're trying to play to, Joe also has the ability to close questions single-handedly without requiring the community's support. What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: There was something with Joe's behavior - instead of voting on the merits of the content, Joe voted based on how the community would react or behave.  Yes, there will always be a handful of people who disagree with a duplicate closure.  Does that mean that *no* question can ever be closed as a dupe and then *must* be answered?

Comment: @Makoto the version of events in your comment doesn't match the one described in Jim's answer. In the version Jim described, Joe still votes to close as a dupe; his *voting* was not in any way influenced but what he thought the community might do.

Comment: @MrUpsidown: I agree that the answer is not answering what you asked. But I will not say "*Nothing's wrong*". Repeatedly answering the questions those are supposed to be closed is also a problem. But again, this is not what we are discussing here...

Comment: @AmitJoshi you are absolutely right. Makoto's comment above made me re-re-read that answer and I finally got what JimG most likely meant. I agree, it's not the right behavior.