# NAA flags declined because the question should be deleted (but I can't vote to delete)

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I recently had a few flags declined because the moderator thought that the entire question should've been closed and/or deleted. However, I can't vote to delete yet because I don't have enough reputation. Voting to close wouldn't completely solve the problem, either, because the answers were upvoted and it wouldn't Roomba.

What do they want us to do instead? If I flagged the whole thing for moderator intervention, wouldn't they just decline it on the grounds that it doesn't require moderator intervention?

This seems somewhat unreasonable to me. The fact that the entire question should've been deleted doesn't make it an answer, and it seems unreasonable to decline a perfectly correct flag. Also, this implies that whenever you flag an answer you also have to judge whether the question is close-worthy and/or delete-worthy; shouldn't those be separate decisions?

**Edit:** It seems like some of the discussion has focused on "maybe your NAA flag was incorrect." That may well be the case, but if that's the case, then shouldn't the moderator have declined it as "no evidence to support" rather than "I agree that it's NAA, but you still shouldn't have flagged it"?

**Further edit:** One particular case to focus on: the entire question is too broad, and all of the answers are link-only. The OP was not asking for off-site resources. In this case, my understanding is that I should vote to close the question and also flag the answers as NAA (which they are). Is this correct? How would a moderator handle those? Is it reasonable to decline the flag on the basis that you should just delete the entire question, even though the flags were technically correct?

Comment: Oh, look at that. Another case where "rules" used separatelly makes sense, but when put together they just reach the Catch 22 conondrum.

Comment: This is a poorly documented question, but I'd channel that the mod wants you to vote to close the question first.  You have enough rep to do that.  Review the many previous "My NAA flag was rejected" questions.

Comment: @HansPassant That doesn't make a lot of sense in my opinion, though - the decision about whether or not to close a question should be separate from whether the answers to the question are, in fact, answers.

Comment: The mod rejected your flag, end of story.  He helpfully recommended a different approach, I trust it was not a wrong one.  You can in turn help me to stop guessing at this by linking to the Q+A.

Comment: If you think a question needs to be closed/deleted, what do the answers have to do with it? If the answers were attempts to answer a bad question, that doesn't mean they aren't answers.

Comment: The mod who handled the flags replied to those flags: *the post is off-topic, please vote to close the question instead of flagging all the answers individually.*.  The first step to a question being deleted is it being closed - so do that and let those who can vote to delete do so if needed. Putting a dozen NAA flags in the review queue is treating the symptom and not the cause. Once the question is gone - so are the answers. If you're concerned and can see it might not get enough eyes on it and won't roomba then feel free to custom flag the question, explain the situation and we'll review it

Comment: Put another way... Voting to close puts it in the CV queue... If people agree and it gets closed, then it's probably just 3 delete votes away and it's sorted. Flagging 4 answers on a Q  means 4 reviewers per each answer have to recommend deletion/vote to delete. That's using reviewer votes (you only get so many reviews per day). If it happens some of those answers happen to be positively scored then there's a mod flag raised about a disputed review we need to look at. So now, we have possibly 12-18 people involved spending time not addressing the root issue instead of at most 5.

Comment: (then to sort out the root issue, you need 5-8 people again anyway - just don't worry about you can't do everything you'd like by yourself - you don't have to - you don't *need* to. Do what you can to do to get the ball rolling and get it put in front of others and move on and don't sweat it)

Comment: The real answer to "What do they want us to do instead?" is that they want you to gather more reputation so you _can_ start deleting questions. Presumably the idea is that most people with around your rep don't have enough background to know what to delete yet, and should be focusing on other things instead. The fact that you've caught on more quickly than most is a good thing, but it means you also need to be smart/flexible/whatever enough to deal with that minor annoyance until your rep catches up to you. Vote to close, maybe comment that it's deletable, and… that's all you can do for now.

Comment: @abarnert The implication would be that we can't flag low quality answers to low quality questions.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes, but if the only problem is that a tiny number of people who've learned the ins and outs of moderation on Stack Overflow so quickly that their rep hasn't kept up with their knowledge can't do that for a short time, is that really a problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: The thing is, just because you cannot act on it, does not mean it cannot be acted on by the community at large. If something is not within your power to handle because you don't have enough rep, then it isn't something you should be worrying about. If you don't think that those who can handle it are doing a good enough job handling it, all the more reason to Get Some Repz and start contributing in that manner.

Comment: did you vote down these answers? (per my experience this often pushes them into LQ queue even without flagging... or more precisely system raises auto-flag that does it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **Further edit:** One particular case to focus on: the entire question is too broad, and all of the answers are link-only. The OP was not asking for off-site resources. In this case, my understanding is that I should vote to close the question and also flag the answers as NAA (which they aren't). Is this correct? How would a moderator handle those? Is it reasonable to decline the flag on the basis that you should just delete the entire question, even though the flags were technically correct?

OK, I went and looked at your flags. The majority of them were raised on questions that were closed years ago. I'm not sure how you came across them, but now that I understand the context of your flags better I have to reiterate what Jon and I have said about not sweating these off-topic questions more than you need or are able to.

If you *still* want to facilitate their deletion, as Jon said it's OK to flag them for moderator intervention in this case, explaining that getting the question deleted through normal means isn't feasible because the answers are upvoted. I understand that not all moderators may take kindly to such a request, but I think this is one area where moderators really need to work with users.

My point here is, don't fall into the trap that so many people do of fixating so much on the answers and the NAA flags that you miss the forest for the trees. We're trying to equip you so you can use your flags more efficiently, helping us deal with problems without cluttering up the queue with NAA flags that may or may not be completely effective. There are enough problems with fresh content on the site that it would be a shame for you to waste so many NAA flags on just one question from six years ago that's not actively harming the site.

---

If the answers were truly NAA in the most egregious sense ("me too", "thanks", ["me](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BreadEggsBreadedEggs) [too](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MemeticMutation) [thanks"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife), "What error are you getting?", "Your question is bad and you should feel bad"), then

> the post is off-topic, please vote to close the question instead of flagging all the answers individually.

was indeed *not* the appropriate way to respond to your flags. Those types of posts should be deleted whether the question is on-topic or off-topic. You flagged them as NAA, the community failed to handle your flags in time, they landed in our queue, they're our problem now. We should delete the offending answers. End of story.

If the answers were attempts to answer an off-topic question... then that response is justified. You do not use NAA flags to chip away at an off-topic question that has answers. The question being off-topic does not make an answer to it any less of an answer. If a question is off-topic, vote to close it, get it on its way to deletion (even if you can't vote to delete it yourself), and move on to the next problem. If the question and its answers are actively harmful but the Roomba can't do its job, enlist the help of trusted users or perhaps SOCVR. Otherwise, don't worry too much about the question sticking around; it's closed, the message is sent. (The principle here is the same as in [this previous answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314395/is-a-self-answer-of-looks-like-i-had-a-typo-really-not-naa/314398#314398).)

Comment: Precedent-wise, does that mean that NAA flags on anything but the most egregious cases will be declined if the question ends up getting closed?

Comment: @EJoshuaS, NAA flags on NAAs won't get declined. NAA flags on answers which answer the off topic question, get declined.

Comment: @EJoshuaS note that the bar for NAA is quite high, irrespective of the question.

Comment: @BhargavRao Like link only answers to questions asking for recommendations?

Comment: @user2285236, oh yes, that'd get declined for sure. Check the canonical [meta on NAAs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/). *There's really only one valid exception to this rule, and that's when the question is: "Suggest me some tutorials where i can learn quick." Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer - but when the question is kinda asking for bad answers this is to be expected. Close or flag the question and move on*

Comment: @EJoshuaS: That's a strange question to ask. No other precedent is being set here than "don't use NAA on answers that answer the question". What happens to the question doesn't change the nature of an answer or otherwise.

Comment: Even if the question gets edited into something different altogether (e.g. in an attempt to meet the site rules), what was once an answer to the original question would still sufficiently resemble an attempt to answer a question - not thanks, a request for clarification or a cry for help, which would be the same no matter how much a question could reasonably change - that NAA would still be a poor choice for such answers. The topic of questions changing enough to make existing answers obsolete has been covered in abundance elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think it's a strange question at all, actually. My understanding is that link-only answers might be an answer if that's what the OP was asking for (in which case the question itself is probably garbage and should be closed as off-topic). But, in that case, the correct "declined" reason is "it actually *is* an answer" - not "you're correct that it's not an answer, but we're going to decline it anyway because you should've voted to close instead." If the moderator felt that it was, in fact, an answer, shouldn't they have declined it as "no evidence to support"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I think you would've cleared so much confusion if you _at least_ quoted the answer into your question. My understanding of NAA flags is that they should only be used to flag a post that's **not an answer**. Period. They shouldn't be used to flag _an answer_, even if it's a bad one, and even if it's a wrong one. You didn't make it clear if that "answer" actually qualified for an NAA flag. If it did, then the first half of this answer does answer your question.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I agree completely - being a bad or incorrect answer is a reason to downvote, not a reason to flag as NAA. I don't flag as VLQ or NAA merely for being incorrect. However, if it really was a case where I flagged something that actually *was* an answer as NAA, why didn't they just decline it for being wrong outright? "You're wrong" would be preferable to "you're technically correct, but we're going to decline it anyway."

Comment: Dear BoltClock (ping to @EJoshuaS too), I got a NAA flag declined three days ago for [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837439/is-there-a-tool-that-can-re-order-a-net-source-file/1837463#1837463), which is nothing but a BROKEN LINK. Please help us to figure out how to cleanup those posts in those conditions.

Comment: Question: Is it ever valid to raise an NAA on a question that's already closed?

Comment: @Nisarg Shah: As I said several comments up, "What happens to the question doesn't change the nature of an answer or otherwise."

Answer (score 1):

As [BoltClock mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370681/3956566), they were indeed answers, so there's not need to reiterate that.

I understand your frustration in wanting to curate the site's content and not having sufficient tools in places. It does pay to choose your battles and to put things into perspective when filtering content.

There's plenty of closed posts with upvoted answers, some of which were posted years ago and since then the scope of the site has changed. This question falls into that category. Essentially these posts do no harm to the site. In fact they can be useful.

If an old off topic question receives a new answer (often an opportunity for a spammer to link in a product), then by all means close the question (and if it's spam flag it). Beyond that there's no urgent need to delete the question.

On the another issue, when flagging multiple posts that are being flagged for the same reason (in this case you wanted to delete them so the question would roomba). It would be better to make one custom flag than to flag each answer individually. The same for any flag for a *related* pattern, flag one post.

> What do they want us to do instead?

In general if you believe a mod flag would be declined, and have no other flagging options, it goes back to either rallying for changes in the system or acceptance.