# User removal: Is there a way to preserve important knowledge?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-users

As far as I have understood the primary objective of Stack Overflow is to be ***a system for knowledge management and also preserving knowledge for others***. 
This is why I usually update questions with the correct answers even if I already have solved a problem.

If a user is leaving Stack Overflow for no matter which reason I wonder if there is a way to preserve (at least meaningful) questions and answers? Usually I see some reputation change in my notifications I do not even see which question or answer was affected after a user was removed.

It is not like I care a lot about the reputation loss however I care about meaningful answers (or meaningful answers of mine on a deleted users question) being removed. Is there a way to see which question is affected?

I did not find clarification about this in the docs. Are meaningful answers or questions transferred to community wiki? Not according to the comments in this question from four years ago (*[Grace Period to recover deleted answer content (User Removed)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276508/grace-period-to-recover-deleted-answer-content-user-removed)*).

Comment: I think you are confusing account removal with voting correction. The answer is not deleted AFAIK the removed user's vote is

Comment: User removal doesn't remove content; it just removes the user (unless that content is spam or otherwise not useful anyway).

Comment: @RobertHarvey There's one exception: _The system will automatically delete any post with a negative score when its owner's account is deleted, unless the post is a question that has at least one positively-scored answer._ [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/369403). This means that on downvoted questions, your answers that have no votes by other users than the user that just got deleted will get removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When an account is deleted, their positively-scoring posts *all* remain on the site, undeleted. The account name on the post is anonymised (the display name is replaced with `user1244252`, so the user id number prefixed with `user`).

Posts with a negative score *are* deleted, [unless it is a question with answers with a positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote/312594#312594).

Don't confuse content posted by an account with the votes that the account cast on *your* content. Votes cast by the account *are* usually deleted, but for accounts with a lot of outgoing votes to a lot of different users, the community management team [may opt to keep the votes, in exceptional cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/140890).

Moderators also have the option to *destroy* an account. This is reserved for spam and troll accounts, when destroying an account all content is deleted with the account, and additional measures are put into place to prevent the account from returning. See it as a ['salted earth' option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_the_earth) for accounts that only created content we really don't want.